# Why is duplicate search still awful?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search

The search functionality for searching duplicate questions does not deliver great results.

For example, when searching for `NullReferenceException` there is exactly [one canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Here's how to programmatically identify that question:

1. It has topic fit since it uses the word `NullReferenceException` a lot. [In fact it is number 1 by relevance in the regular Stack Overflow search when searching for this exact word.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nullreferenceexception)
2. It has tons of upvotes.
3. It has been used to close questions as duplicates probably 1000 times.
4. When a closing user searches for `NullReferenceException` he will pick this question 99.9% of the time. In other words: Learn from the behavior of closing users.
5. That question has a high incoming link count.

I request that the duplicate search be improved significantly. Possibly by factoring in these 5 signals that I just explained.

The duplicate search is so bad right now that it might be better to just use the normal search functionality. I often find myself using Google search to find the (obvious) question that I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: [Boost duplicate post search results by incoming link count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232131)

Comment: But personally I usually reach for a google `site:stackoverflow.com` search, if the subject isn't already on the Python chatroom [canon list](http://sopython.com/canon/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is also the Stack Exchange [search page](http://stackexchange.com/search?) (in case you wanted to see if it was going to be a dup on another site).

Comment: I agree. I find that it delivers *very poor* results, even when you get most of the non-noise words In the title correct.

Comment: Agree. If you want people to find duplicates, improve the tools before thinking of [giving rep for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5).

Comment: @JonasCz I don't see the connection. If anything people deserve rep *more* for finding duplicates with crappy tools.

Comment: @MartinSmith, True. People deserve a reward for finding duplicates, no matter what tools they use.

Comment: Odd, I never use this so never noticed that it was bad.  I always have the dup URL already copied and just paste it in.  If the machine would be good at guessing at dups then you would probably not have to look at them in the first place :)  Distilling an entire post to just a single keyword, well, not so simple.

Comment: I always search, google 1st, then SO b4 asking a ?. Only if I can't find an answer anywhere do I pose the ?, Consistently within minutes of asking a ?, there ,many legitimate requests to close it as a dupe  pointing to an answer to my ?. 2me, this means SO must improve the search. Beyond that, when I try to remove my question on the grounds that it has been asked and answered, I get a warning that I will be banned from asking future ?  if I remove my ?, You can't have it both ways. It if is a dupe, let me remove it & more importantly help me avoid asking in the 1st place by making search work

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour what's so awful about it? It demonstrates the issue with a little bit of fluff and the answer is good. Anyway, all of these points are heuristics. They tend to be a positive impact. One counter-example means nothing.

Comment: @usr the code does not actually demonstrate the problem at hand, which would be closed or heavily downvoted today.

Comment: It is worth noting that `Why is duplicate search still awful?` is an awful formulation for a feature request.  More suitable, perhaps, would be `Can we improve duplicate search?`.  The former has a simple answer - because nobody has invested the time and energy to make duplicate search better.  If it's a feature request, then request the feature.

Comment: Update: As far as I can tell nothing has changed. Can someone from the team comment why such a core feature is left in this dismal state?

Comment: Surprise. It is 2018, and it still sucks. And similar requests like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369657/could-the-close-as-duplicate-ui-be-made-more-useful-please ... also don't cause any observable reaction.

Comment: In 2021 it's the same, I can be shown with [NoClassDefFound error](http://prntscr.com/1vqwi23) and it's clearly an issue for me ... hard to find good question...

Answer (score 4):

I am glad you asked this question. I answer plenty of Android-based questions and I often see many duplicated questions that have to do with Android layouts that start with: "`NullpointerException in XML`" or "`my layout crashes, why?`".

So from my experience, I can definitely agree that your second point: "`It has tons of upvotes.`" helps when I search for duplicates but most of the time the question has to have an almost exact word for word duplicated question in order for the "`duplicate search`" to find it.

Answer (score -11):

I would suggest searching for duplicates on Google and using the ID you find in your duplicate search on Stack Overflow.

Google will always do a better job.

This answer has created a lot of comments & a lot of downvotes, but interestingly no additional answers.

My point, I think, which I didn't clarify, is that Stack Exchange's resources could be better used on things other than search. Any search that Stack Exchange Inc. implements will always be worse than what Google will do, so in my opinion it is a waste of resources & instead Google search should be integrated into Stack Overflow.

Roll on another -10.

Comment: Google does not do a better job when it comes to saving time. A good, built-in search should immediately find such obvious candidates. I rarely look for duplicates because it is so time consuming.

Comment: Moreover, Google search results don't help when suggesting questions as possible duplicates as you're creating a new question.

Comment: Even if Google currently does a better job, improving the existing search when asking a question would reduce the number of duplicate questions asked by those who _do not_ Google first.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I don't really know what the Stack Overflow team does all day. I don't feel any changes to the core product. It seems kind of finished which is fine. Now finish search as well and lay this to rest.

Comment: Your answer is the one that makes sense. Using google, I can find a good duplicate within seconds. The SO built in search just sucks. Especially when using the mobile. And if you can't get your own search right, then include the google search. This answer deserves a 100 upvotes, and to be accepted. The reality is that this question is 3 years old, and the duplicate search still lacks big time compared to google. Sometimes reality just wins.