# “Ask a question” wizard prototype

Tags: discussion, questions, ask-question-wizard-2018, ask-question-form

You're all probably wondering who I am and where Joe is. I'm one of the developers on the [Developer Affinity & Growth team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth) with him, and I'm excited to tell you about a prototype that we'd love your feedback on.

Questions and answers are what Stack Overflow is all about. The starting point for a great Q&A site are good questions. We all know that asking a good question is an art, and humans - particularly those in a hurry - aren't naturally good at it all the time. We've also known for a long time that Stack Overflow needs to provide a better "ask a question" experience, especially for people new to the community. We think we can make the experience less intimidating, help people avoid common mistakes when asking, and improve the quality of questions with a bit more guidance baked into the process.

### What have we done?

- Last year we [gathered a lot of ideas from the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions) on what kind of improvements we could invest in.
- We [created a measure of question quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) to score improvements
- We ran an [initial experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363051/ask-a-question-template-v1-experiment-results) to test out our question quality measure

### We're off to see the wizard

[image: Screenshot of the question body section of the wizard. Section prompts: summarize, Provide background, show your code, describe expected and actual results]

Our next step is to run an experiment on a prototype "ask a question" wizard. Before we do, we'd love for you all to kick the tires on it and give us feedback. Our goal is to get this experiment up and running in July. The experiment will be focused on newer question askers, so experienced community members won't see it, except during this comment period.

**[Check out the prototype here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard)** (Please note this will post a *real* question on SO)

Feel free to add answers below to suggest improvements to copy, the flow or any part of the experience. We'll review the suggestions to find targeted improvements before running the experiment.

And, of course, once we have some data on how things went we'll report back here.

Comment: I like the flow in the forward direction, but can you add a Back button on screens after the initial one? The browser back button doesn't seem to always take me back where I expect it to go (the immediate previous screen in the wizard).

Comment: ...Okay, fine.  Color me [skeptically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358265/1079354) optimistic about this wizard.  I'm going to peruse it later to see if there's anything that really juts out.

Comment: Are the examples of great question descriptions hand-picked or computer generated (like review audits)?

Comment: Is this going to be a thing for all users now? Or just new / low rep users?

Comment: I'm curious, how much of the verbiage and/or functionality was directly harvested from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard?

Comment: Ctrl+K seems not to be working in the Show-your-code-section.

Comment: Will this be available in a single view? I don't like the "one-page-per-input" feel of it.

Comment: I DIDN'T REALIZE IT WAS LIVE!   I posted a really bad 'i++ + ++i' question:)   Luckily, I deleted it before it got -100 votes:)

Comment: On the description tab, nowhere does it tells the poster to explain his/her question in a minimalistic manner. A guide on how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example for each popular tag will be a good addition. The guide may tell users to post more details in the question, but it doesn't discourage them from posting overly verbose questions.

Comment: @ps2goat Hopefully never. The point of a wizard is to guide you **on rails** through the question asking process. A wizard should *not* put everything on one page (otherwise it's just a 'template') where you can just scroll down and enter stuff in the last box and hit Submit. But as someone who has asked 16 questions on main, you will likely never see this in production anyway.

Comment: @TylerH I understand we want clean data, but sometimes you'll get no data if the user doesn't deem the experience worthwhile.  Not everyone posts bad questions.  Maybe it can be an earned badge/action or something.

Comment: This guided mode is a big improvement but I'd definitely rephrase "your code" to "your **reproducible** code with an appropriate simulation of any relevant datum or data"

Comment: @ps2goat If the user doesn't deem asking the question worthwhile, then I'm not sure we would want their question on the site in the first place. We have tried the "all on the same page" approach before... that's exactly what we have now (and have had since inception). This is something different because what we have now isn't working well.

Comment: Let me just say **thank you** for trying to make this less bug reporty inspiring.

Comment: On mobile, the wizard doesn't really wizard -- it shows the original multiple choice, then instead of walking you through how to write the question, it sends you to the normal ask a question page. [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Needs a back button.

Comment: How about automatically treating what is entered in the "Show your code" section as... .. code? (I.e. no need for ctrl+k on this section)

Comment: Is it just me, or is this wizard in dire need of a hat?

Comment: Could I request this as an optional feature for higher rep members, I think this could be useful stencil for them too.

Comment: Can we put a warning/disclaimer/block that the prototype will really make a question? I did the same as @MartinJames

Comment: Maybe have the Tag suggestions box appear for a little longer - it stays up if the text you've written is in the suggestions, but if I write `Excel ` the box disappears as soon as I place the space at the end and I may not have noticed there was `Excel-` if I didn't know it already existed.

Comment: @downvote-flagger I was just about to post this same comment.

Comment: Why does it not show the "similar answers" if finds?  `We found similar c# questions that match your title, "hungarian notation"`

Comment: Are the form fields supposed to autofocus on wizard navigation? They don't and it feels clunky.

Comment: What's up with this constant pat on the back? Why everything is `Great`? For adults with normal self-esteem that seems like we are being treated as 5 years old- they do need a constant reminder that everything they do is great. Normal adults do not.

Comment: @SergeyA It's likely part of Stack Overflow's effort to make the site more welcoming. And the more personalized, 'warm' responses have been shown to elicit better reactions from the target audience; it is a common theme in the marketing/advertiser world.

Comment: All of this just made my day. I love the community recommendation feature. Keeps it friendly, but gets them to the right stack. A+ guys!

Comment: I'm not sure about the title. When I ask a question, writing the title is usually the last thing I do.

Comment: @SergeyA Great comment! ;)

Comment: Wish I had this when I first started asking questions on SO a couple years ago and just got roasted over and over because I had no idea what I was doing

Comment: Amazing! I like it!

Comment: You're going to get the users who are put off by wizards - it's inevitable. Are you going to provide a way for the user to switch to a standard question format?  Also, maybe providing some prior examples of tags (e.g. if any of the more common tags are spotted in the user's question detail) would be beneficial.

Comment: I am restricted from asking questions and cannot find a genuine reason for that

Comment: The Wizard should only apply to people Below say 10000 reputation.  I have umpteen thousand reputation, and help-wizards aren't helpful, every question is unique and requires a special consideration from my wizard staff and wizard hat, no two questions are alike and trying to assembly-line this is only a help for users who are obviously adding damaging artifacts.  Add a way to turn off the wizard in the settings page.

Comment: @SergeyA When a programmer joins Stack Overflow it is as if he is born again. In that sense, a first-time asker is about five minutes old. Let's give our newborns some encouragement!

Comment: Perhaps users who have achieved the 'Nice Question' badge could use the old format? I don't think a rep threshold is a good idea, as I could potentially get all my rep without having asked a question. Having said that, I don't see the wizard as being a great imposition, apart from the fact that the steps are ass backwards for the way I enter details. I always enter description, and then use that to craft the title and tags.

Comment: @EricLeschinski isn't 10,000 rep a bit too high? I think it should be somewhere around 500 rep. At that level is the review privilege, so I assume that we think that users who reach 500 rep know at least what counts as a good post (whether question or answer)

Comment: I actually asked something like this one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368851/new-feature-readily-available-so-proper-format which will give proper format, but all I get are downvotes, Tell me now why this tool which will create a proper format for asking questions got to have a positive score?

Comment: Next we will have a wizard for answers?

Comment: @EricLeschinski Holy crap dude. 10,000 rep before you stop seeing the wizard?? That's extremely high. It should be more like 500, as Keale says. If you're worried that new users could get that much rep really quickly and start posting bad questions before they've learned how the site works, consider this: If they get 500 rep really quickly, doesn't that imply they're doing well already?

Comment: @EricLeschinski But in case you didn't read the post, it does actually say that: `The experiment will be focused on newer question askers, so experienced community members won't see it`

Comment: For all those asking for a "back" button you did realise there were tabs at the top so you can just go back and (worse) click forward to the end and just post a question.

Comment: I like it how it tells you witch site is on topic for those types of questions.

Comment: @Keale I have seen 30K users asking absolutely off topic questions. More than once, and more than single user. I don't think there should be any threshold. Seriously, if someone asks so many questions that going through wizard is a hurdle, then maybe this is an indication that those questions maybe should not have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think 30K users asking off topic questions are *outliers*, I guess? Besides, I'm basing my comment on how we give privileges here, which I assume have been established to be working somehow. (Or not, since there are many robo-reviewers at 2K rep grumble grumble)

Comment: @Keale Point is that reputation, while it can be some indication of how well person knows the site, does not imply person does know the site and the rules. There are seriously off-topic questions posted by users between 1K and 10K on daily basis. So my original comment stands and IMHO there should be no reputation limit.

Comment: @SergeyA I agree with you. This sort of validation would start to annoy me after one or two questions. I feel like this screen can be skipped all together, or perhaps only shown the first time you select a specific option on the "Type of question" page.

Comment: It isn't a real wizard without [this guy](https://i.imgur.com/0RPecXV.png).

Comment: But... where's Joe?

Comment: Well constructed but ultimately just a really good way to enable the laziest of attitudes. "Here, we'll do it all for you". Isn't that what got us into this mess in the first place? The overwhelming "niceness" is just misteaching people that it's okay not to pay any attention or take any personal responsibility.

Comment: Writing questions yourself is not and has never been hard.

Comment: How can I go back to unguided mode i.e. the way as it is today ? IMO forcing a template on an user is always a limiting factor and makes life hard.. since now I need to think in a specific format while asking a question. My problem may not fit the template shown here.

Comment: Note that there are a number of software packages which are not code-driven, but use a graphical environment instead to construct mathematical models or control algorithms as block diagrams (e.g. "Simulink" tag). For those types of questions, there is no code as such to post. People should be encouraged to post one or more screenshots of their models, with relevant parameters of the various blocks inside the model, as well the overall model settings. If the model runs but doesn't produce the expected results, these should be posted as well with some justification.

Comment: Definitely agree `Show your code` should be automatically indented.

Comment: When I get shown similar questions I'd like the amount of upvotes to influence the order. I asked about how to get the directory of the exe file for a C# application and got listed questions that were marked as duplicates instead of the question they were duplicates of.

Comment: Also whenever I hit the back button I don't want to be back to the starting point, I want to go back one step. Similarly, this wizard could use a back button next to its next button, too. And lastly, the window with the "Great!" message could be merged with the next window for all options that don't redirect me to a different website like superuser. All in all I love the new wizard and even though I'm not new I'm looking forward to using it as soon as it's open to everyone.

Comment: @TylerH SO should keep in mind that there are cultural differences there. In many non-US cultures, that kind of hyperbole (which seems to be pretty entrenched in the US) is not the norm, and in some it may be actively confusing or even disconcerting.

Comment: There is two things I would want to add. **1** warning when you upload pictures that you should not upload pictures of text/code. **2** when you include arrays format them correctly and preferably in such a way that you can copy paste them to code.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, can you specify what you're replying to? I have several comments under the question, but none of them are using hyperbole, so I'm not sure what you're replying to.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, my bad. I was answering to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype?noredirect=1#comment601673_369682) regarding "pats on the back".

Comment: @Raphael Still not sure where you see any hyperbole, but yeah, some cultures are in general more polite and friendly than others. This is an American site in America, though; while there are users from all over the world, the culture that the owners are clearly wanting to foster is one that is viewed positively in America: being nice. It's even [in the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). I agree it could be very confusing for people from countries like Germany and Russia, where this kind of behavior is famously absent.

Comment: @TylerH You didn't hyperbole; I was referring to hyperbolic language. It seems to me that there's quite the inflation of "positive" language in the US under the pretext of "being nice", resulting in people sometimes using positive language without actually being nice. (Whereas in Germany, we know how to be nice without using "great" thrice in every sentence, so to speak.) But I think this is not the right place to discuss culture; I just wanted to note that there_are_ differences. The same wording may come across as unfriendly or elitist or patronizing or brown-nosing, depending on the reader.

Comment: Also, remember *A new feature is a Bug if it can't be turned Off...* I like the new wizard, but there needs to by a bypass so experienced users can simply ask a question as it is now. (like Bugzilla, a nice little *Advanced* link in the heading or corner works). The tags wizard is contradictory. It says *"Don't include version numbers"*, but as soon as you start typing *C++*, *C++11*, etc.. pops up. It should say *"Don't include a version number unless asking about a specific version"*. Good effort and idea to all who are working on the wizard.

Comment: Nice effort, I like this feature.

Comment: The prototype is no longer online.  Not sure if that's intentional or not.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think it's ever implemented? ...

Comment: For SE dev team: When will this be done? ........

Comment: We've taken the prototype down in preparation for an experiment we're about to run with this. More to come soon :)

Comment: Hah. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/610573

Answer (score 441):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

I am not a UX designer, but in the "What's your title?" page of the wizard, I feel like the examples should be grouped by example, not by good or bad. See below for visual.
[image]

which would result in something looking like this.

[image]

It makes more sense to have this grouping to me, but I could just be crazy.

Comment: Agreed, the only difference I'd suggest is going with the negative example first.

Comment: @BrianKung Strong disagreement about negative examples first --- someone who is skimming should see the positive example first. Compare to the journalistic writing style of putting the most important information at the head of the piece and filling in details below.

Comment: @rob my argument would be that the negative examples are shorter, more generic, and easier to recognize in your own writing if you're in the middle of writing a poor title. Seeing them first makes it less likely to skim over the entirety of the block. It's also more clear what to do if your title matches the negative pattern - stop and continue reading the tip. Finally, progressing from a worse place to a better place is a natural progression for a lot of people - like red, green, refactor.

Comment: Also I feel that the "Say" and "Don't say" are redundant due to the symbol in front of them.

Comment: Further, there is [no error message on the title tab if your title is too short](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369762/5389131).

Comment: @Luuklag: It depends.  In some cultures, the X is a positive symbol or the check is a negative symbol (or rarely, both at once).  Red and green have varying cultural interpretations and [may not be visible at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorblindness).  You need English to disambiguate this.

Comment: Can we also include a `Do: How to Fix 'Headers already Sent'`,`Don't: PHP: How to fix 'Headers already Sent'` because tags are tags?

Comment: @BrianKung - I agree with Rob on positive example first. Despite your good logic of natural progression and recognition in writing, from a psychological standpoint giving an instruction of what to do yields better results than forbidding something. Putting something first gives it emphasis. I vote positive example first.

Comment: Concerning this particular example, you may want to have a look at [discussion on asking R-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567); broadly speaking R community does not like questions that deviate from that format without valid reasons. It's likely that the *is there a function* question would be closed quickly with people suggesting to use Google or [rseek](https://rseek.org) and come back with better defined problem.

Answer (score 310):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

I think the *"We found similar questions"* page should be skipped if there isn't one:

[image]

Comment: You're definitely right on this one. We shouldn't be showing this if there aren't actually any similar questions :)

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Sucks that there's not a lot of questions for **jgdfjgdfhgdfj kk**, that thing is always giving me issues

Comment: @James_Parsons The problem is you're using an old version! Everyone is using **jgdfjgdfhgdfj kk++** now.

Comment: My jgdfjgdfhgdfj kk keeps giving me a null pointer exception. Better ask a new question about that...

Comment: Even better news would be, if the suggested questions would follow the tags asker had chosen on earlier stage.

Comment: I used `We found similar c# questions that match your title, "hungarian notation"`  -  - none were shown .. what about [hungarian-notation-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768255/hungarian-notation-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @JonChan That and the primary call to action following, _"Do any of these answer your question?"_ probably shouldn't be, _"Next."_ Perhaps something like, _"None of these answer my question. Let's create a new one."_

Comment: What the jgdfjgdfhgdfj kk is going on here?

Comment: But in case of SO: If there were no similar questions found, it is likely, that it actually is a **jgdfjgdfhgdfj kk** question and therefore should get auto-flagged as spam ;)

Comment: @MA-Maddin - because new programming languages aren't a thing, or?

Comment: I also find that a lot of the suggested questions concern different tags. Could these be filtered to only show questions that have at least one tag in common with the question I'm writing? (E.g. I just asked a question about list comprehensions in Python - half of the suggestions were about Haskell.)

Comment: @acdr: The danger with that is that the user has typed in bad tags, no similar questions will be found, even if it's a question that has been asked a million times before.

Answer (score 222):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

You can't go back in the wizard. If you hit your mouse or browser's Back button, you start the wizard all over again - and the title, had you already entered it, is lost when you do so.

Comment: There are links in blue above the wizard that are for each step that let you go back to the specific section that you want, but I feel like a back button like you suggest would be a lot more logical.

Comment: multi-step and draft support perhaps?

Comment: @DavyM: Depends on where you are at in the wizard. Those don't show up when you selected "I need a software recommendation".

Comment: At the very least the wizard should be making an entry into the browser history.  In my case I tried a couple of the off topic option on the first step and there is no option whatsoever to go "back", including in my browser.

Comment: Anyone like me who has dedicated system-wide back and forward buttons on their mouse and uses them all the time is going to be so mad using this unless the history stack is used appropriately.

Comment: Having some way to go to previous steps (back button and/or browser navigation) is planned for when the experiment goes out.

Comment: @BoltClock You’re still using a mouse in 2018? You don’t have a trackpad or touch screen so you can just say “Alexa, tell Siri to have Google go back” in hopes that one of the AIs can work out which multitouch gesture to use?

Answer (score 190):

I really like the setup for this. Asking them to put the tags in up front yields a massive advantage in presenting the user with targeted existing material.

One major thing is missing though, in the similar questions page.

[image]

> We found similar javascript questions that match your title, "how do i sort an array"

Did it really though? No. It didn't take the tag into question when examining similar posts and it gave back, pardon my French, a bunch of ... well, nothing useful.

Had it considered the tag used, by searching `[javascript] how do i sort an array` it would have found these instead:

[image]

Note the post with a 1764 score, 869,153 views, and a canonical duplicate target for 251 posts. That is just the first result. **Can we please consider the tags that users enter in the similar questions search?**

Comment: Agreed; I assume the ability to filter possible duplicates and intelligently suggest hints/block known bad stuff is the actual reason for putting tags first... hopefully it wasn't just a random straw poll.

Comment: Same issue on my dry run... the copy actually said "we found similar 'Java' questions", but only one of the 4 similar questions actually had a java tag on it at all.

Comment: the point is **the wizard should order the similar questions based on total votes and answers**

Comment: @aswzen - That isn't really the point I am making here, you may suggest that in a separate answer. All this is asking for is to consider tags with the search being used for similar questions. I feel that is a good, easy, first step towards significant progress. Beyond that, it may also make sense to [remove non essential words](https://www.link-assistant.com/seo-stop-words.html) rank the questions by the amount of questions linked to them (i.e. duplicate targets) then by votes. However, this suggestion is merely to take the tags used into consideration.

Comment: I noticed this problem too, with the [c] [winapi] tags, when I typed in "How do I enumerate all PCI devices" most of the questions had nothing to do with [c] or [winapi].

Comment: The question titles are also not enough to determine similarity: you should probably actually just load the search results page :)

Answer (score 147):

Where do the headings go? When I enter this:

[image: headings]

I get this:

[image: headings gone]

And that doesn't really make for a readable question. Perhaps prepend some headers, like **What I've tried:** before those sections.

Comment: Maybe give the option to include the headings. By default turn it on and on the last screen before sending let the asker review his question and add buttons to remove each heading.

Comment: One approach would be to have the prompts fade out/get covered by the responses on the earlier page, as a hint that the asker is meant to be making statements rather than responding to queries.

Comment: The headings should **not** be included because this is not a question template. This is a general idea of what structure the user should follow. So headings should not be necessary there. – But your attempt shows a different problem, that users may end up “answering” to those section headings, instead of writing self-contained stuff.

Comment: @poke yes, that's my point exactly. I don't necessarily want to see those headings in each new question, but in that case the user should be motivated to write down their expectations in the form of _"I expect to ..."_

Comment: When I was building this, I also considered adding the section headers as comments above each portion of copy once a person got to the review step. I think it's worth revisiting, with special attention to the concerns you and @poke brought up.

Comment: @JonChan Why not using this text as a placeholder that disappears when the user starts writing: `placeholder="Describe expected and actual results"`? Then the user will think *"Oh this text `Describe expected... ` disappears, so I should formulate my question so that it's understandable without it"*. I think it might solve the problem. What do you think CodeCaster?

Comment: In my opinion, the [headings are one of the most significant points of interest in the wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363052/1026459). Their text, and they way they are handled (including versus excluding versus passively saving) will be a large factor in the success of questions asked with this feature.

Comment: Related: https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/24325/stack-overflow-trials-question-templates-hugely-improves-question-quality

Comment: Can you make it visually apparent the headers aren't part of the post?  Right now they look like pre-filled text.  If it's clear they aren't part of the post body I think you retain the benefit and guide the asker to write text that is complete w/o the prompts.

Comment: You want them to enter 4 different bits of text.  Perhaps 4 separate "textareas" with the heading/prompt above it would clarify that it's not part of the output post.

Comment: linking @jinglesthula 's connected answer/response: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370279/9259306

Answer (score 133):

Some notes from first runthrough:

1. Treat "Show your code" area as code, indent it for the user. At least prompt if it's not indented.
2. Warn the OP to NOT post images when describing desired results and observed output, unless the image (and not text of any kind) is indeed the output.

More notes. This time I put in "java" for a tag and "Why do I get this warning?" question title.

3. The list of the possible matches contains a question with score -4 asked on c99. Some better filtering/matching is needed.
4. If we already have a -4 question with exactly this title, let's tell the user to change the title (Finally! Some use for bad questions!).

Comment: On #1, I would say don't automatically do it for the user, show the user how to do it. Otherwise, next time they ask a question and it doesn't automatically format for them, they'll be confused as to why it's not in a `code block`.

Comment: @DavyM OK, then if the user fails to indent, let's keep prompting them till they get it. Do not let unindented code pass through

Comment: **Say** that code should be indented 4 spaces. It's the single most useful piece of information that is currently missing from the question submission page.

Comment: @n.m. , the wizard already says so. But it's easy to miss or misinterpret. Provide a button to index like in the real question form? My point is, do not let the user proceed till they learn and/or the code is properly indented.

Comment: Well, I have missed it! Probably isn't prominent enough.

Comment: Re: indenting code: the edit box doesn't have controls to format as code (or any other formatting buttons for that matter), and Ctrl-K didn't work for me either. The only way to properly format the code in that box is to manually indent each line with four spaces.

Comment: _[ShamelessPromotion]_ Related to "No images of text / code": [Feature request: Raise / Remove reputation limit for showing “Do not upload code screenshots” message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367875/raise-remove-reputation-limit-for-showing-do-not-upload-code-screenshots-mes) _[/ShamelessPromotion]_

Comment: Regarding code formatting in "guided mode", there's a lot of consistent feedback that it isn't apparent that a user should be doing that. We're going to review some of these suggestions and try improving it for the next round.

Comment: I was just about to post 1,3, & 4 on my own.  Instead I'll pile on to yours.  Especially #1 & #3.

Comment: Can you split these into 4 separate answers?  Then we can vote on each one separately.  My upvote is for #1 (although the others are worthwhile).

Comment: Wish I had the capacity to store up votes and add them to this one. The point about not letting users just use images of console interaction and output is essential. I can imagine there could be situations that needed images in a code section, but efforts to post images should be subjected to a gauntlet of "are your really really sure that an image is essential?" sorts of questions.

Answer (score 104):

You ask me *"Do any of these answer your question?"*, but the button text says <kbd>Next</kbd>. Perhaps it could read something like *"No, I still want to ask a new question"*? That way users understand exactly what the button is doing and there's some discouragement to blindly ask anyway.

[image]

Comment: "No, I still want to ask a new question" -> "No, I still want to ask a new, _different_ question"

Comment: or "No, none of these answer my question."

Comment: @Mistella That feels quite negative though.

Comment: @DavidG Perhaps. I think I was more focused on how the wording might encourage people to actually look at some of the existing questions instead of just skimming through some of the titles before posting their own question -- less work to just hit next. Another thought: maybe it would feel less negative if the "No" was moved to the right, and a "Yes" inserted where the "No" button currently is? (I saw that another person's feedback was that they thought a "Yes" button should be added: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369731/9259306)

Comment: @Mistella You're effectively repeating the question back at them so I find the text a little redundant, hence why I focussed on getting the user to confirm they *still* want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 91):

When recommending other sites,  the positivity is **overwhelming**.

[image]

In situations like this, we need to have the OP acknowledge two things have happened:

- They've posted their question in the wrong place, and should direct their question there
- Their question ***might*** be acceptable there, but it has a very real chance of ***not*** being acceptable.

How about this copy instead?

[image]

Comment: I tried to put myself in the mindset of a person knowing nothing about the SE sites coming to ask about a software recommendation, and when I read both the existing one and your suggestion, my eyes see "Great" then my hand skips right to the blue box without reading anything else, because in my mind: "obviously none of the other stuff is as important as the big 'Great!' because it's all smaller, so no reason to read it". I think the text you provide is good and important, but I think it needs to be presented first without something in a bigger font before it.

Comment: Honestly I wanted to see if I could get rid of "Great" but then the entire thing kinda...fell apart, and I don't really wordsmith that well...hopefully that can be addressed too.

Comment: What about leaving the super-positive text, but having the button take them directly to the softrwarerecs on-topic FAQ instead of their front page or ask page?

Comment: Agree 100% with @DavyM. If I, as a new user, see that gigantic "Great!" I would almost immediately click whatever button/link is presented to get me to finally post my question.

Comment: How about "Woopsie!" instead of "Great!"?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Can you not see the wall of text crumbling after "Woopsie!"?  It's like there's an *error* and the rest kinda just blurs together to become one with eternity as the message and button no longer hold meaning.  Wordsmithing is hard, I'll grant you that.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the part that explains why we're seeing this is burried in the "tip" part, and the paragraph under "Great!" is talking about something a new user would have no idea about. "Woopsie! This question might not fly!" or *something* that better conveys "you're about to post a question that's likely off-topic". Or, move the "tip" above "Great!", make it bolder, and change "Great!" for "But don't worry!" or something.

Comment: FAQ should be *linked*. Maybe to the Meta's [meta-tag:faq]?

Comment: How about **"Look over here!"** instead of **"Great!"**. In itself it captures that there is a place to find such answers, that that place isn't here, and that there is no 'guarantee' that the answer is there. More over, it is vague enough to nudge people to read the rest of the text.

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369772/839601)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: If you present it as an error, the user may immediately go back and try to answer questions "the right way" in order to bypass this screen entirely.  Better to have them immediately hit the blue button without reading, than to immediately hit the *back* button without reading.

Comment: I think that `The Software Recommendations community is here ...` does not make it obvious that this is the _title_ of a site, it may simply be overlooked. I would recommend changing this to `The community of "Software Recommendations" [formatted as link], another site in the Stack Exchange network, is here ...` or something similar.

Comment: Just link them to the FAQ/asking guidelines of the other site directly.

Comment: Came here to make similar comment. "The Super User community is here" does not at all convey that "actually, there is a *different* website you should go and use instead". "Here" is really misleading and confusing. Suggestion: "Oh, in that case - you should try our sister site, Super User. It's designed for general questions about software and hardware."

Comment: Instead of "Great!", why not simply "OK". That doesn't convey positive or negative, but probably implies that some more information is coming, so it's worth reading on. It's pretty much the reaction you'd get asking a real person a question they can't answer: "Can I have a Big Mac meal please?" "OK, this is a Police Station, but maybe try McDonalds just down the road".

Comment: I also find the approach "positivity overwhelming" But, having worked in different countries, I recognized the style. It is difficult to explain. The best I can come up with is that  in many cultures such an answer would be seen as, .... as... "in your face"  probably is the nearest expression. Therefore I also advocate to tone it down a bit.

Answer (score 86):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering a tag, you get the errors "Title is missing." and "Body is missing." popping up at weird places:

[image: is missing]

This also colors the border of the title and question textbox/area red on the next screens.

Also, the Title screen doesn't support <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. The title screen also doesn't display any errors, for example for a title < 15 characters.

Comment: This definitely shouldn't be happening. I'll investigate.

Comment: Really nice find, 100% a bug.

Comment: This freaked me out when it happened.  I think it tried to submit a form or something but it shouldn't do that yet...

Answer (score 82):

Let's take a look at the first page:

[image]

You have optimized for debugging questions first. I get that a lot of questions from new users are useless debugging questions, so I'm okay with that being at the top of the list.

Next we have two off-topic honeypots, which is OK, I guess.

Next we have an option for homework questions. Homework questions aren't a "type" of question. A homework question could be a debugging question, or a how-to question, or a why question, etc... The only thing that makes a homework question a homework question is that the asker was given the question for homework. This distinction is irrelevant.

Finally you have an "other" option, let's take a look at where that takes us:

[image]

You lay out a set of requirements for on-topic questions. The first of which is:

> - Includes a bit of source code, and

[**Only debugging questions require code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281). How-to questions do not require code. How-to questions that include code are actually debugging questions (if the OP includes some code that doesn't achieve the desired result, the objective for answerers is to fix the code, i.e. debugging question).

This section looks very similar to the first section on the ["What topics can I ask about here?" help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But notice how the help center article says *"We **feel** the **best** Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"*

This in no way means that questions without code are off-topic. It means that some people who call themselves "we" like questions with code in them some unknown amount more than questions without code; but—just as I personally feel the best Stack Overflow questions are the timeless how-to questions whose answers have helped countless users despite having included no code in the question at all—that is neither here nor there.

---

What can a new user gather from this wizard? Only useless debugging questions are on-topic. All other questions are off-topic... unless you were assigned the question for homework.

Comment: That's exactly my impression of this wizard. If I want to ask a question about some  API of a specific library, I don't know which option to choose. At least the sentence "I have a question about my code" needs to be rephrased.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173359/discussion-between-joe-friend-and-tiny-giant).

Comment: This isn't a debugging question but would fit great in this wizard and provides/requires code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981827/reversed-positional-parameters

Comment: @Pluto it is a debugging question because you provided an attempt that didn't achieve the desired result.

Comment: You seem to forget that 99.5% of all How-to questions that do not provide code (in one way or another) are worth closing as "unclear", "too broad" or "duplicate".

Comment: I don't think I should have to prove that non-debugging questions are not inherently off-topic solely because they don't contain code every time this comes up. I'm leaving it at that. You can hate on these questions all you want but the **fact** of the matter is that **only debugging questions require code**, and contrary to popular belief there is a lot more to stack overflow than just endless variations of the same useless debugging questions. Have a nice day @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Maybe you did not get my concern here. I do see the problem of people trying to close valid questions because they think they would need to contain code, even if they really don't. This is not what this is about here. Here, we want to know if the new guide is useful or not. Your answer fails to tell in how far this guide would prevent valid questions from being asked. If someone wants to ask a valid question and is forced to give some source code in it, it will not make their question worse. It would also not turn their question into a debugging problem per se.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I completely disagree with your entire comment. I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: I just went through the complete wizard to ask a How-to question without any code and it works perfectly. You need to click "other" of course and then just follow the steps. So it's really unclear what this "only debugging questions require code" has to do with the guide.

Comment: I roughly agree with you but think you're overstating your case. In particular, I don't agree with the idea that just containing code innately turns a question into a debugging question. However, I agree that good questions needn't contain code (and so does the community; just go and look at the top-voted questions on the site and observe that many don't contain code).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, of course you can decide to deliberately disobey the unambiguous instructions forbidding you from asking a question without code in it. But it seems to me that your stance - which as I understand it amounts to *"we should have this rule, you're wrong to criticise the rule, and also everyone should disregard the rule completely"* - is a pretty confused position to take on pretty much any rule, including this one.

Answer (score 67):

I am dubious about:

[image]

While I agree with this in general, there are cases where it is better to include a version number.  For example in the case of problems that only occeur in a specific version.

Taken from the [python3-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3-x) tag:

---

### Tagging recommendation:

Use the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag for all Python related questions. If you believe your question includes issues specific to the incompatible Python 2.x or Python 3.x, in addition to the main [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, use [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). If you believe your question may be even more specific, you may include a version specific tag, such as [python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5).

---

Should the asking wizard be altered to omit this?

Comment: I would rather like to see a warning not to use irrelevant tags (I really don't need to know you are programming in android studio)

Comment: @AndréKool  I agree, this is potentially misleading for a beginner here, and filtering questions might become harder.

Comment: Just curious...did you intentionally blur out that screenshot or did you just take a screenshot with some tool that can only produce stuff in that quality? On the subject of the answer; I totally agree, this suggestion to not use version-specific tags is flat out *wrong* in cases where the question is about version-specific code.

Comment: Maybe "Don't include version numbers unless you have a reason to believe the version is relevant"? That's basically what the `python` tag wiki is saying—but I don't think there's a way to say it that's both concise and clear, much less concise and clear and general to all tags. Something vague like "… unless you have reason to believe…" may be the best that could be done. And I'm not sure it's even necessary, since most of the time they won't have such a reason.

Comment: I'd rather they always include the version number. It can make a big difference in what features are available, and in some cases a known bug or issue with an older version of the software may be in play.

Comment: C# also might not be the best example, because when you put C# in the tags, it automatically suggests tags that contain C# versions.

Comment: I rather they include the version number on the body. That way it doesn't prevents from adding more useful tags, like frameworks, libraries, etc.

Comment: The first thing I entered was `c++`, and among the tag suggestions that popped up were `c++11` and `c++14`...

Comment: @Braiam  That's ok until there is  a question with a title like `Function X in Language V does not do M` then it becomes easier to read if it is tagged with X and V rather than have that in the title (which is what ultimately seems to happen).

Comment: @indiv  Almost prompting the user to put them in.  I thing effort should be made so those do not come up, rather than saying "Don't use these tags (even if you might need them)".

Comment: @JeffreyKemp  Indeed,  there are languages with multiple versions for example in Python (there are 2 and 3) both are different from each other, and for a person who only knows 1 answering would involve looking at both those for 2 and 3.  If they are tagged no such problem exists since they immediatly know the version/problem with features avalable.

Comment: @Simon The consensus of the SO Python community—as reflected in the tag wiki intro quoted in the question—is the exact opposite of what you're suggesting: most questions should _not_ be tagged with a specific version. (And if that's true for Python, a language where 2.x and 3.x are pretty different, and the first example that came to your mind, I suspect it's true for many other languages.)

Comment: It's also pretty weird that it shows [tag:c#4], when the tag is actually named [tag:c#-4.0]. Seems like that would fall more under the category of not creating new tags

Comment: Version number makes sense in a lot of cases, What if we give a solution as per current version, whereas OP is using an older one. Many times, we have to ask them to post their versions in the questions. Though for many Databases we have relevant version tags which IMHO is very useful

Answer (score 66):

Do we *really* need to explicitly call out homework problems?

[image]

If the policy on homework problems [is truly universal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354), then declaring it as a homework problem is a useless moniker which would only serve to fuel the negative stigma that homework questions here already have.  The code of someone trying to solve a homework problem is *still* "their code", so I feel like the first radio satisfies this need.

I could be proven wrong, but I'm not sure this is necessary.

Comment: Since these two button appear to lead to the same path through the wizard, I agree. However, I think it would be interesting to see the difference in questions posted through those two buttons, and see if the homework one could later be customized to help folks improve those kinds of questions.

Comment: Neither changes the question that eventually gets asked, it just changes the guidance given to the user on how to ask their question which is able to be more specific for that use case.  More specifically, it's telling them to describe the specific problem they're having implementing whatever their homework is, rather than to focus on what the actual homework problem is.

Comment: @Servy I think the one thing that really should be different in homework problems is that they need to be clear about what the requirements are. When the obvious answer is "use a `for` loop instead of a `while`", but the assignment says "you must use a `while` loop", that information has to be in the question or the answers will be useless. Or when the obvious answer is "fix that function to return a tuple instead of storing into global variables", but that function was given by the teacher and can't be changed. Etc. And that kind of thing almost never comes up in non-homework code.

Comment: @abarnert That's not really any different than non-homework problems.  Lots of professional problems still involve people with constraints, often even constraints that don't seem sensible.

Comment: @Servy It’s pretty rare for professional problems to have constraints that ridiculous. But, more importantly, people with professional problems tend to know when they’re working under ridiculous conditions like “can’t use BSD-licensed software” even if they’re complete novices to Stack Overflow, but students usually have no idea which conditions are ridiculous.

Comment: @abarnert:  You're ***joking***.  There are professionals who have to use Java **1.3** because of contracts signed long before they graduated *high school*.  There are professionals who don't have the ability to move off of 32-bit systems due to some arcane and obscure mission critical application which refuses to run on an AMD64 architecture.  There are professionals whose *very job* is to work in ancient systems and structures which haven't been touched in *decades*.  (I'm looking at the Voyager developers and their new McLarens, with a tinge of jealousy.)

Comment: @abarnert Sure.  Students often don't know lots of things that are relevant when asking programming questions.  I'm not opposed to including guidance that those types of questions are more likely to need to hear, including explicitly telling them to lay out constraints for the problem.  It's just that that isn't a problem unique to homework, just a more frequent occurrence.

Comment: @abarnert:  All that said, "ridiculous" doesn't really matter.  They're constraints like any other constraint.  Whether or not they're under the pretense of academia is fundamentally irrelevant to whether or not their question is on-topic for the site.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, but those professionals _know_ they have to use Java 1.3, and will usually mention that. Whereas a student who’s allowed to use Java 8 but isn’t allowed to use some obvious language feature because it’s part of next week’s classes doesn’t know that’s something they need to mention.

Comment: @abarnert:  I've gotta say...of the good homework questions I've answered, it's been  *vanishingly* rare to not see their constraints clearly laid out.  At a minimum, if an answer makes assumptions and plows forward with a solution that they can't really use or understand, that's usually addressed with comments and edits to the main question to highlight those constraints.  It's a process, but I've never seen this process diverge any from the same process we'd have to use to get professionals to tease out their constraints.

Comment: @Makoto Homework problems are not guaranteed to have ridiculous requirements that the asker doesn’t know are ridiculous, and professional problems are not guaranteed not to—but the probabilities are different enough that it’s at least plausible that it’s worth giving different guidance in the two cases: explicitly telling the homework askers to lay out all the constraints they’re operating under. Because in practice, it’s a real problem that people get an answer and only then say “That works when I run it’s but the assignment says I have to use a list”, making the answer a waste of time.

Comment: @Makoto That being said, the most common reason for that problem (mostly only in Python, but that may just be because the other languages I look at are rarely used in intro programming courses…) is people trying to pretend they’re not asking about homework until it becomes unavoidable to admit it. So maybe just having a “Homework” that tells them it’s ok as long as they do the same research etc. will be sufficient to reduce the problems.

Comment: You have a point; via comments we can eke out the artificial constraints so common in homework. But we're programmers. It makes sense to automate a manual process, and this menu can help with that. Nothing personal, this is meta after all, but -1.

Comment: @MSalters:  I'm worried that you have missed my point.  Nothing about this wizard is even remotely automated, nor would this wizard suddenly automate the process of asking homework questions.  Constraints are constraints and if the policy really is universal, we should be looking at this as constraints and nothing else.

Comment: Shuffle the options when displayed. See if there's a statistical difference for people checking "homework questions."

Comment: People asking questions about homework who simply copy and paste the homework assignment into the OP so that strangers can do their homework for them are a pet peeve of mine.  I'm in favour of eliminating this radio button.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude:  That doesn't necessarily *fix* the issue you're having...I mean I **get** where you're coming from, ***but***...

Answer (score 60):

This tip says you should format your code, but doesn't show how. Maybe a link to [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the tip would be enough

[image]

Answer (score 52):

Somewhere you need to explicitly prompt them for any Exceptions or Error messages.  Possibly in the Guided Mode page?

I see a **LOT** of questions posted where the OP mentions an exception but does not include the actual detail, which results in a lot of back-and-forth in the comments encouraging them to post it.  Encouraging them to include this in the first place would eliminate that noise and frustration.

Comment: And that's why I'd like to separate Runtime Error into its own path,

Comment: I sort of agree - make error/exception a separate path from general code questions.  Splitting runtime vs compile time seems too discrete, and doesn't make sense for every language

Comment: I debated with myself about mentioning Linker Errors too :) Dukeling's answer has a better approach.

Answer (score 51):

[image]

This statement is true, to some extent. However, if anything really important is left out, or if the post is just a rough draft, it is just as likely the question will get closed before it gets edited by the OP.

It may be best to inform them that posting the question will yield immediate results and scrutiny. They will be expected to respond to any clarifications immediately. NOW NOW NOW. Something that really hammers in the point that this question is about to be seen by a lot of real people at once the split second it is actually posted.

Many new users are not aware of how instantaneous the response is here. As a result, there is a severe lack of attentiveness. I think there is an opportunity with this message at this point to at least give them some sort of warning about what is to come once the question is actually submitted.

Comment: "500 people will read this question in the next three minutes.  Are you sure this is how you want it to look?"  (replace 500 with whatever number)

Comment: We do see a lot of people disappearing immediately after posting a question. It would definitely be nice to let them know that they should stick around and look at any comments asking for further detail.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom the amount of followers in the tag?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom "N people will read this question and ask you for more information in the next M minutes. Are you sure this is how you want it to look?" might be better -- it encourages them to stick around and ensure that they're present to update the question in response to comments.

Answer (score 49):

We should split "questions about my code" (and "homework problem") into:

- Why do I get this error?

  (Have an "Exact error message" section)
- Why am I getting the wrong output?

  (Have "Output I get" and "Output I want" sections)
- How does this code work?

  Tip: Tell us which specific part of the code you don't understand.
  Tip: See if you can find documentation about the part you don't understand first, and whether that answers your question.
- Can you write code for me?

  ??? (No?)

With the exception of the last point, all the others should probably also have a tip about debugging.

Comment: This feels a little bit like [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369687/4916627) to me...

Comment: @AndréKool Yep. Upvoted :) I like this set of options much better than my own, I wish I could donate my answer's upvotes.

Comment: I would also like to have a [code review honeypot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369729/2415161): „I want to know how to improve my (already working) code“

Comment: I just noticed I read something into your answer that is not actually there: I propose the first page should still have the exact same wording but when this option is selected there is a second page prompting for a selection out of these subpoints. Otherwise it would be overwhelming.

Comment: I want to upvote this approximately 3 more times.

Answer (score 42):

Putting myself in the shoes of a new user, I'm not sure what these numbers are supposed to mean.
Maybe we need to put a legend, or make this tabular?

[image]

Might just be a minor nitpick though.

Comment: Putting myself in my own shoes even I don't know what the numbers on the right mean.

Comment: @TylerH on the left: green background = with accepted answer. Number = current question score. On the right: number of answers on that question.

Comment: I tried to put myself in the shoes of a new user but I [can't find my legs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: @Braiam I think we need to put labels to those numbers in one way or another?

Comment: I think you're right about this. As a new user, I don't think I'd understand what these numbers mean without a legend.

Comment: @JonChan Yes. Intuitively, I knew the meaning of the numbers on the left because I've seen that 'design' before. But I assumed the mindset of a new user, and I found that there aren't any labels of some sort for both of the numbers. Sure, not knowing the meaning doesn't do any harm, but some users might think that those numbers might be there for a reason, and some might get confused.

Comment: @Braiam thinking about it, it doesn't really make a lot of sense. Why is the accepted-status indicated by colour behind _the question's score_, rather than behind the number of answers?

Comment: @leftaroundabout as Keale said, it's used elsewhere. The UI is pretty consistent at least on that behavior.

Answer (score 40):

First, it looks really nice, and looks like it has potential of reducing duplicated, and maybe even helping people find answers to their questions.

One thing I noticed is that many validations we have today are not displayed while filling the title, but are displayed only in the "Review" step - they would look much better at the appropriate step, after filling the title.
We may want to re-think how they fit in and whether they are still needed.

- The wizard is missing keyword-based guides. Note that this is based on the title, not tags:

  [image: regex-specific resources, tips, and links]
- The warning on [potentially poor titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351883/7586) is also removed:

  [image: Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question.]
- And, of course, this <del>problem</del> issue:

  [image: These words are not allowed in titles: 'problem']

Comment: The additional tips for each tag could be something like the tag-wikis, so the community is in charge of it, so it doesn't have to be hardcoded and can be individual for each tag.

Comment: Related:  the warning about similar titles being frequently downvoted does not appear for me when I *enter* the Review tab, but it does appear when I *modify the title* in the Review tab.  (I.e., that particular validation seems to run only on keypress in the Review tab).  If this is not immediately reproducible, then note that I did switch back and forth between Description and Review a few times before I noticed.

Answer (score 40):

**TLDR: Consider not showing the question editor in the review step.**

The last step, "Review" has a format similar to the normal "Ask a Question" page. This may have been intentional, to get new users used to what that would look like, but I had hoped that the ask wizard would address a problem that I have suspected some new users run into. I've seen a lot of questions where I thought, "surely this person overlooked the question preview. If they knew their question was going to be posted looking like that, they would've tried to do something about it." I guess for some of them, that was probably wishful thinking, but hopefully not all.

I think having the editor available in the review stage draws attention away from the question preview. I think new users might benefit more from a confirmation step with just the preview, where the editor isn't shown and they get a prompt like "Your question will look *exactly like this*, and [lots of people will start looking at it immediately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369725). Are you sure you want to post it?" There's a similar [feature request for the main ask page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process), and in some of the discussion there I see some points against it in that context, but maybe in the wizard it would be more fitting, since it's already a multi-step process, and you've made it simple to go back to previous steps to make changes.

Maybe it would also be helpful to mention in the text under "Review your question" that markdown editing help is available in the editor. "If you're having trouble formatting your question, click the question mark in the editor toolbar for help." I've seen many new users who didn't notice that was there until someone pointed it out to them.

Comment: Or just put the preview above the question editor instead of below it.

Answer (score 38):

Putting myself into the shoes of someone who has never used SO I'd say the "tags" section needs a lot more information:

[image]

Specifically some information on **what a "tag" is** and also information giving rough details on what to do with the expanse of white staring at them. Specifically some of the information that is currently in the ["What are tags, and how should I use them?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) help page, something like:

> ### What languages, technologies, and/or frameworks is your question about?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.
>   Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be
>   able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined
>   categories. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more information.
>
> Each question may only contain 5 tags at a maximum, so choose the ones
>   that best describe your question.
>
> To add a tag start typing into the box below. Select the  relevant tags from the list that appears underneath.

This might seem obvious to us but it may not be to someone new to the site. Tags are an abstract concept that often new people get wrong, misunderstand, etc. The point of a wizard is to guide people through this minefield. This currently isn't really adding anything useful in this aspect. It's just showing the same information in a slightly different ordering.

Comment: When I first came to SO I was doing some iOS development, and I remember I used to think it was important to tag every question with "iphone", "xcode", "objective-c", "ios", and "cocoa-touch", which were usually not *wrong* tags, but they were rarely all totally necessary (e.g. "xcode" is likely not relevant to a question purely about arrays in objective c). I also thought I would be less likely to get an answer if I didn't fill all 5 tags for every question. So yes, I agree that more guidance would be good.

Answer (score 38):

I hope this picture speaks for itself:

[image: Useless search results]

No matter what, that list should start with this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). It should also allow sorting using different criteria, such as upvote count or created/last modified dates.

Honestly: if you do **not** fix the really bad internal search for duplicated questions, then you can as well drop this part of the wizard. 
I have closed zillions of Java questions, and I almost never use the internal search. Because it is of no value to me, an experienced member of the community. Not a newbie making his very first steps here.

And remember, this is really not a new [complaint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289364/why-is-duplicate-search-still-awful).

And to be really clear: this answer is not a "duplicate" of Callums. He complains about links giving the wrong impression. I am complaining about the wrong links being shown.

Finally: having the wizard is a great idea, and I hope it works out. It is just that "finding duplicates" is such an annoying undertaking using the built-in search (and UI capabilities).

Comment: In order for this to work, there would be some significant changes to the way the duplicate search operates. It would need to strip out non essential words, similar to search engines ([here is the standard list](https://www.link-assistant.com/seo-stop-words.html). That gets us to `[java] nullpointerexception`. It would then need to order the results (they are currently unordered), preferably by the number of posts linked to the post, and then by votes. This would get us pretty far, but is a lot of work. I think just starting with at least using the tag in the search would be a good step.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, this requires work. But as said: if the existing search isn't improved significantly, it really doesn't matter too much how the search results are displayed. Because they don't help. I also think that this place here isn't ideal to discuss the technical aspects of how to get to a better search.

Comment: Agreed - Travis J actually answered this question with this criticism already - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369724/2756409

Comment: I did the same experiment and came to the same conclusion **fail**.

Comment: you mean AI on SO?

Comment: Hey, remember when [this was supposed to be improved as part of the Channels initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams/352082#comment491517_352082)?

Answer (score 34):

The wizard strikes me as a little backwards: Current progression is tags -> title -> body.

When *I* write a question, I always write the body *first*, then the title, then take some of the suggested tags. Why not move tags to after the body, in order to take advantage of the tag suggester?

The title I can understand, since it uses the fancy possible-duplicate-suggester it could save time (and result in fewer duplicates) to write the title first.

Comment: My guess is that some of the later suggestions are (or are eventually intended to be) tag specific.  I.e. the examples shown use examples specific to your tag(s), or tags with specific gotchas (like regex questions or SQL questions not mentioning the specific implementation they're using).  I do think that having the title last is worthwhile, but I can imagine tags going either way.

Comment: I think it should be just as possible to identify duplicates based on the body as on the title. I also always write the body before the title.

Comment: Considering how broken the duplicate question filter is, and considering how actual question bodies better-inform question titles, I think question titles should be the *last* thing that people write (though I've already [written at length](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard) about that). As far as tags first, I think it could be helpful to provide context clues for the system to pick up on certain phrases based on what is tagged. E.g. if they try to put in [tag:gdpr], they can be prompted with Law.SE before ever typing in their question.

Comment: See Travis J's answer for a more fleshed out explanation on the benefit of tags-first.

Comment: I agree the title should be last. I've read (and fixed) numerous questions that end with some variant of "so, in conclusion, I guess what I'm trying to ask is <thing that would have made a really good title>" while the existing title is along the lines of "noun noun error noun". I think that the tags should come *first* however, because picking those kicks the syntax highlighter into action.

Comment: How about a re-prompt at the end saying "Now that you've written your question, can you improve the title to better describe it?"

Comment: That'd be great too, @JeffreyBosboom. I'd support that.

Comment: I agree that the body should come before the title and tags. Writing the question body forces me to consider my angle of attack on a problem. It's kind of like writing the question and then summing it up in just a few words to create a title. I can write a specific title and include only the best tags.

Answer (score 31):

This looks great for about half the potentially-good questions on SO—questions about debugging some attempted code, and about getting unstuck on a homework or non-homework coding problem. And it looks great for dissuading two major categories of off-topic questions, those that belong on softwarerecs and superuser.

But what about the other half of the potentially good questions? If I were a new user and wanted answers to a specific question about, say, working out how two different string search algorithms will perform on my dataset, or fixing a `virtualenv` setup so it stops picking up Python 3.5 installation instead of 3.6, or getting Xcode tooltips working again after a failed docs update, or understanding how Python implements `isinstance`… I think the wizard might be more misleading than helpful. I might:

- misdirect myself to softwarerecs, or
- click "specific question" and then be baffled when it asks for my code, or
- click "other" and then be scared off when it tells me to include a bit of source code,or
- click "other" and then include a bunch of irrelevant source code to my question, possibly instead of the information about, e.g., how I installed Python 3.5 and 3.6 and `virtualenv` and what platform I'm on—which would have been obviously useful if the wizard hadn't confused me.

So, I think the wizard needs to be broader, to cover other kinds of questions that can be potentially just as good as debugging and stuck-coding problems.

Comment: Someone who made enough research to understand that they need to fix "a virtualenv setup so it stops picking up Python 3.5 installation instead of 3.6" - or any of your examples, really - does not need the wizard and will likely opt out (I would :) ). The wizard is more for the people who ask at the level of "Python gave me this error: how come?"

Comment: @Arkadiy These are all based on (my possibly imperfect memory of…) recent questions by users with single-digit rep that started off unanswerable, but were edited into shape (and started getting upvotes and answers) after some back-and-forth in the comments. So, I don’t think those users necessarily are experienced enough to jump past the wizard and confidently ask  a good question without guidance; they may well be misled or scared off by the wizard instead.

Comment: There are a lot of potentially good questions even newbies might want to ask that are discouraged by the current starting menu.  Questions about a programming language ("Does C++ have garbage collection?"), questions about algorithms ("How to analyze time complexity of merge sort?"), questions about tools ("How to convert project to 64-bit in Visual Studio?"), questions about APIs ("Which HDC do I need to pass to GetDIBits?").

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes, that's pretty close to what I was trying to get at here, and maybe explained better than I explained it.

Answer (score 27):

Maybe a more general issue,  but why is there no character limit to the tag box? You can overload it and cause text run off for days!

[image]

Answer (score 26):

The help box on the right side is a little... jumpy!

[image]

Comment: I've seen other parts of the UI do this same thing. What browser are you on?

Comment: @Undo It's Chrome 67 on Windows, but have also confirmed in Edge. FWIW I'm currently using a terrible 100 year old laptop with a fairly low resolution, so window size/media queries may be an issue.

Answer (score 24):

I mostly track the EE site but filter the SO site for "verilog", "vhdl" or "fpga" tags.
Thus my first action was to select:

[image]

The "next" button dead-ends<sup>1</sup> me one a page which says. 
"The Super User community is here to help you with a software or hardware issue."

I suggest you give the user a choice between going to EE, Super user or go back to SO (e.g. they have an FPGA, Verilog or VHDL question which is the grey area between SW and HW. )

1<sub>No, there is no way to go BACK the BACK button on my browser is disabled.
That is not only annoying, to me it is rude! "We know what is best for you, do what we say!!! But that issue has already been addressed in other answers"</sub>

Comment: Probably that bullet should say "My computer isn't working" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 23):

This is a more specific version of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369694/4916627).

After you choose software recommendation there isn't a single way to go back:

[image]

Comment: This is also the first option I tested, and was immediately stuck in that page. Also - I found the text really confusing, and I know what they meant. "The Software Recommendations community is here to help you with a software recommendation." - 1. X is here to X, makes sense, bu it isn't clear "Software Recommendations" is a name of a site. 2. Why does it say "here"? It is redirecting to another site ("there").  Maybe something like "Stack Overflow is mainly for code questions, but we have a network site for software recommendations".

Comment: I kinda like this as a feature, actually. If you say you have a recommendation question, it's fine to make you do a little more work to post that question to SO. Still looks like a bug, but I wouldn't be heartbroken if we made posting bad questions harder.

Answer (score 22):

Related to [other answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369684/839601):

> When recommending other sites,  the positivity is **overwhelming**...

Indiscriminately pushing users to other sites carries a risk of eventually breaking proposed design. Something like that already happened in the past when some site communities forced Stack Overflow to remove them from migration targets ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152596/165773), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134642/165773)). If other sites get flooded by inappropriate questions from users misled by wizard, they can demand removing "quasi migration" references.

Links to other sites currently refer user to main pages of these sites. I think it would be safer if these would lead to *help/on-topic* pages instead:

- [Ask Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- [Ask Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Since the wizard already prepared a user that they will have to go some extra steps prior to posting, it would be only natural if they pass one extra step of going through other site help center page prior to posting over there, wouldn't it.

For a smoother user experience, I would also recommend showing an intermediate wizard page prior to throwing users to the other site. With text like...

> ${SiteName} has specific guidance on what kind questions are welcome over there. You are expected to review and follow this guidance if you plan to ask there...

...and actions allowing to pick whether to proceed to that site or go back to the prior wizard page.

It's worth noting that referring users to the Help Center pages instead of the sites' main pages addresses (at least partially) concerns raised in [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773) and multiple discussions [linked to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/277607?lq=1).

---

<sup>(I also think it would be *nice* if you somehow announce at respective site metas that you are going to direct users over there in such an explicit way. Because at the scale of Stack Overflow this might have quite a noticeable impact on these sites.)</sup>

Comment: I agree.  If they really want to ask a question on the other site they'll find the button eventually.

Comment: what if it's their first time on the site and they don't know another site is best

Answer (score 20):

Another thing that might be useful is some heuristic matching on the user's text. There are things that don't belong in *every* question, and asking enough questions to figure out in advance when they are and aren't relevant could delay getting to the actual question so badly that people just leave, but do belong in a lot of questions, and often require back-and-forth comments to get from new users. For example:

- If the user mentions "error" or "exception", suggest that they copy and paste the compiler error, exception traceback, etc. into their question (and format it appropriately).
- If the user mentions a popular tag but didn't include that tag in their question, ask whether they're sure they didn't want to add the protocol-buffers tag.

(I'm sure there at least half a dozen of these that would be useful, but I wanted to push the basic idea of matching text in addition to guided questions here, so I'll stop with two.)

Comment: Off-the-cuff suggestion: jsfiddle/godbolt/ideone link -> include actual code (can be friendlier then the red warning box)

Comment: The licenses with those playgrounds are not compatible with Stack Overflows license. Importing the code without the owner's consent (and probably even with the owner's consent) would be violating their original license. This is why we as users are not supposed to do that for users either. All we can really do is make it clear to the user that questions should be self contained. @JeffreyBosboom

Comment: @TinyGiant I wasn't proposing to do it automatically.  I just think the wizard can do better than the red warning box at educating users about why we want the code in their question.  The box is small and immediately in the way of submitting the question, so askers want to just do whatever to satisfy it.  In the wizard, we can prompt them before the preview step, and we have space for a "Why?" heading below the direct instructions.

Answer (score 17):

The very first step, "What type of question do you have?", doesn't help filter out requests for code review. "I have a question about my code" is exactly what someone looking for CR would pick, and their choice is immediately validated by a large, friendly "Great!". Having their questions closed as off-topic after this would probably come as kind of a slap in the face.

Given the amount of CR questions, I think it would be valid to split this into two distinct options:

- I have a problem with my code.
- I would like some feedback on my working code.

Comment: I think the right place would be in (a|[the proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369699/2415161)) split under the first point.

Comment: Code review questions are not inherently off-topic ("how can I make this code faster/less error prone/more magical?"), but they are subject to broadness and clarity issues as every other type of question. For example, "here's my code, what do you think?" Is overly broad, unclear, and opinion-based; but such a question would also be off-topic on CR IIRC. The major difference as I understand it is that we want generalized code that has been reduced to just what is necessary to get the point across, where CR wants the actual project code.

Answer (score 15):

I expected the link to "more examples" to actually lead to more example**S**. Instead it links to a single example at a time (which could be by design).

I can click it again, and again, and again, but it seems there are only two examples and I get each one multiple consecutive times before I get the next one.

[image: More examples]

Comment: Some sort of a list of examples might be good. Or if that opened a dropdown or something.

Comment: Actually if I remember correctly both words are an example, so that amounts to a grand total of 2. So there are actually example**s** but it's not clear that they are two seperate links.

Answer (score 15):

This is probably a very minor thing, but I kinda felt lost after this page. I clicked the very first suggested answer which opened in a new tab and actually answered my question.

After processing it, I closed that tab and came back here, and somehow felt I had to finish the wizard anyway, since the only action is 'next'.

Of course I could just close the tab and be done with it, but I was missing some action to do, some button to press, to indicate that I had been helped.

And actually, it might be quite interesting for SO as well to have an explicit action and gather some metrics on that, to get some useful feedback from users who don't finish the wizard.

[image: No exit?]

Comment: I agree. I had the same experience and I want to click YES, but there was no YES for me. :( Also, sorry to hear about your computer.

Comment: Google tracks (if you don't block it) if you click the back button after checking out the first result, the second result, and so on, and uses that as a ranking input for future queries.  If you track _which_ question satisfied the asker, you can suggest those questions more highly next time.

Comment: Maybe once a link is clicked SO can add a button that says "did you find the answer to your question?" and then the user can say yes (and a congrats screen is shown) or no (and the questions are left along with the next button).  Wouldn't want to make it a pain for those who can't find an answer after clicking several links however.

Answer (score 15):

The prototype looks great.

Minor point I want to confirm is about **DRAFT**

I usually have my question saved as Draft. Yes, there is no explicit buttons on SO to save the question as draft but inside editor after some time the question autosaves and a discard button appears as shown in the image. After this, if I exit the editor and comes back in, I can see my question as is.

[image]

Is there such autosave progress or Draft functionality in wizard? **I propose to save wizard progress or the question as Draft**

Answer (score 14):

When I finish through the wizard and I post the answer I get a banner:

> You did it! You just asked your first question.
>
> Thanks for contributing to the community. We're glad you're here
>
> Tip: Stick around to answer clarifying questions and comments. This
>   will help others answer your question.

I am not sure who will use the wizard, if only the newcomers or people below certain points or ... But in some cases it won't be their first question (that one got downvoted or closed...). Maybe that bit could be rephrased.

Comment: Yeah, the positivity is nice but this is a bit over the top, and in many cases it probably won't even be true as you mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for working on a wizard.

This looks like a bug to me:

I picked "I have a question about my code" but then didn't post any code anywhere, and got all the way through to the final page. Somewhere in there, I should have been prompted (probably when leaving the Guided Mode page with a space for code) about the fact I'd said I was asking a question about my code and hadn't provided any.

Answer (score 12):

### No error message shown on *Title* tab

[image]

If the title is too short (<15 characters) the user cannot use the *Next* button to continue. This is okay, since it is an indication of a **bad title**. However, the user does not get an **error message**. This is very confusing.

At the same time, the user can skip ahead by clicking on the other tabs to go to *Description* or *Review*.

---

The validation message is displayed correctly on the *Review* tab as can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The black listed title words check should be done when asking for the title initially not several screens later on the review.

[image]

Comment: I reported it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369710/7586

Answer (score 11):

Might be worthwhile prompting users if they're **really** sure they want to use a certain tag. For example, `http-status-code-500` [says do not use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500), but I can still add it to a question without complaint. Tags like `regex` should also prompt a user to indicate what dialect of regex they're using. I'm sure there are other examples of commonly misused or confused tags as well that I'm not aware of.

It would be interesting to allow some form of community written logic for tag hinting.

Comment: This would be valuable regardless of how the question is being asked but I'm not sure that there's any sort of indication for the "don't use this tag" tags on the server side that the tags shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Catija: Sadly there isn't, except the regex-based blacklist that straight-up blocks asking a question with it, editing a question to have it, or editing a question without removing it.

Comment: This would deserve an independent question as it is not only related to the wizard. Please post your suggestion as a [new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 11):

I experienced a bug while using this feature. The eventual URL for the question was:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918368/how-can-i-capture-a-value-from-a-header

In the **Show your code.** box, I entered some XML. However, the XML didn't render in the page below. Later, when I clicked **Next**, the input disappeared entirely.

## Screenshots

### The Input Page

[image: The Show your code input box has a bunch of XML in it, as well as the word "test"]

### The Preview

[image: The XML doesn't render in the preview. The preview only shows the word "test"]

### The Review Your Question page

[image: The Review Your Question step has removed the input entirely]

## The Code I Pasted

The code was correctly indented with 4 spaces. The same copy-paste generates this when pasted into this Meta Answer:

---

test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:testCase id="9770a55e-28b4-4382-b47c-91b78303f9d0" discardOkResults="true" failOnError="true" failTestCaseOnErrors="true" keepSession="false" name="WorkOrders TestCase" searchProperties="true" timeout="0" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
    <con:savedRecentRuns>1</con:savedRecentRuns>
    <con:testStep type="restrequest" name="Create 1" id="209811cd-1462-4914-bc0b-6f9e788a3dd1">
        <con:settings/>
        <con:config service="http://example.com" resourcePath="/${#Project#Version}/sample-rest-service" methodName="Create 1" xsi:type="con:RestRequestStep" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <con:restRequest name="Create 1" id="864bddef-ac17-45c7-b5cc-f5a471f2fd61" mediaType="application/json" postQueryString="false">
                <con:request>{"name":"Chris"}</con:request>
            </con:restRequest>
        </con:config>
    </con:testStep>
    <con:testStep type="groovy" name="Capture URL" id="568a0402-bb39-453d-b738-044fb7a1dafa">
        <con:config>
            <script>// ???</script>
        </con:config>
    </con:testStep>
    <con:testStep type="restrequest" name="Delete 1" id="d0a75d1a-3847-4c03-bc85-27e16a61adac">
        <con:restRequest name="Delete 1" id="514d244d-db20-43cf-bff4-5fbbd6c351ac" mediaType="application/json" postQueryString="false">
            <con:parameters>
                <entry key="id" value="${#TestCase#id}" xmlns="http://eviware.com/soapui/config"/>
            </con:parameters>
        </con:restRequest>
    </con:config>
</con:testCase>
```

---

(**^ not a screenshot**)

Comment: The text is actually there but the markdown renderer ignores it. This is a fairly common newbie problem, which definitely should be caught by the wizard.  Indenting the XML four spaces tells Markdown that you are entering a code snippet, not embedding HTML (which newbies are probably not going to want to or know how to do anyway).

Comment: @triples it looks to be indented as expected in the screenshot above, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: To clarify: the text does not render on the *Input Preview* page, and then it disappears entirely when the user moves to the *Review your question* page.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some thoughts of mine when experimenting.

---

I don't like how some off-topic types of things are presented on the first page. Instead, I think this should focus on the things that are on-topic on Stack Overflow. For example, questions about using develop-oriented tools (for example, IDEs, compilers, debuggers) are on-topic, yet that's not a choice. It's a little deceiving that there is a "I need help with a software or hardware issue" that redirects users to Super User - I don't think questions about using Eclipse or Visual Studio or git should be directed to Super User, yet this may direct people there.

Along the same lines, it leads to different "advertising" of other sites on the community. Why does Software Recommendations get a special shout-out on the first page while every other site is hidden behind the "other" (indicating the person is asking about something else).

I think that by focusing on the different types of questions that Stack Overflow is good at would be better. Code that isn't working, code that works but isn't understood, developer tools - these all probably have different needs in the question and should drive users down different workflows.

---

The layout on the "Good News! We found similar questions!" page is weird. I do like the general idea, but I would like to see question bodies there. It's kind of hard to scroll through the list. I have to start opening questions in new tabs. Maybe it'll help, maybe it won't. If I saw snippets of the question body, though, maybe it'll help me narrow down which of the questions I look at deeper to see if I get help.

---

Somewhat related, all of the workflows go to the same Description page. I'm not sure this is a good idea. I think that expectations of homework questions may be different than questions about using a tool, for example. Questions about understanding working code are going to be different than questions about broken code (broken code is going to have error messages and/or wrong output in addition to expected behavior). Maybe this is something that will happen in the future, though.

---

I can definitely see value in this for sites other than Stack Overflow. Many sites have different types of questions. I hope this is being built in a somewhat configurable manner so other sites can take advantage of this if they need to. I can definitely see this being useful on Software Engineering to discourage people from posting things that belong on Stack Overflow (although, in my experience, these are also people blocked from posting on Stack Overflow, so maybe not).

Comment: "Why does Software Recommendations get a special shout-out on the first page" -  The 'recommendation request' off-topic close reason [is by far the most used](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days) excluding debugging help. 5.5% of all closed questions in the last 30 days used that reason, >1500 over a month. Decent volume, handily beating the SU and SF close reasons.

Comment: @Undo That makes sense, thank you. Although it's still a little weird to be presented with both things that are OK to ask about and things that aren't OK to be asked about on the same page. I would think that by hiding these things not to ask about, you'd do more to discourage people from asking about them.

Comment: "*The layout on the "Good News! We found similar questions!" page is weird. I do like the general idea, but I would like to see question bodies there.*" I agree, it may be beneficial since there is now more space there to show a small intro blurb to the question as well.

Answer (score 10):

It's going to be a great feature, I do support the idea.

---

1. At the "Tags" stage, it's worth mentioning that the user can't make up own tags yet. Any non-existent tag should be removed, and/or alternatives should be suggested.

   Being a thoughtful user and having filled my tags at the first stage, I wouldn't want to return to them at the "Review" stage (after 2 other steps) and see "You aren't allowed to create tags, edit them again" or something.
2. At the "Tags" step, we should follow our own rules. If we say "at least 1 tag" and "max 5 tags", the user shouldn't proceed next until they meet the requirements.

   Again, I wouldn't be glad to see any error pop-ups about tags at the final stage, because I have finished with them earlier. If there were no warnings there, why did they appear here?

   Currently, we can continue with any number of tags.
3. At the "Tags" stage, the tip "Don’t include version numbers, like c#4" should be revised.

   I can have an issue only with the `c#4` version, and I am not interested in whether my code runs on other versions. It's not a general `c#` question. Actually, the `c#-4.0` tag has 25k questions. Why were others able to use that tag, but I can't?

   I would suggest a more accurate suggestion, like

   - "Include tags that are crucial to your question only, like `java` (for general questions) or `java-8` (for more specific ones);
   - "Don’t include minor and patch version numbers, like `java-8u172` or `java-10.0.1`".

Answer (score 10):

### New comers shouldn't be able to ask questions in a different language other than English (unless in allowed sites). I've been able to post the question in Bengali, at least SO should add a note there.

[image]

The image shows the question. I was expecting that, my code section will be within a code block even tho, I didn't format it correctly and why I was expecting it because there is a separate section for code but that's not my main concern.

### My Question:

Is it still possible to post a question in a different language other than English? I've seen many new comers post full question in their native language and eventually it gets deleted but it would be better if SO checks this before posting or at least adds a note about that so a user will not post a question in a different language. A use should be able to post a question with text written in a different language but the full question shouldn't be in a different language.

Btw, the test is live (I wasn't expecting it tho) and I've got three down votes :-)

Comment: There are four non-English SO sites - Japanese, Portuguese, Russian and Spanish. Anything else must be here, in English. This is because supporting moderation for non-English sites isn't really possible at the moment. There's more information about this on Area 51: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition

Comment: That's why I posted this here. I saw new users post questions in different languages and that should be taken in account. So, shouldn't allow a user to post a question in a language that is not understandable by others (other than allowed sites) or at least there should be note about it. I've have been able to post it.

Comment: Non-Latin text is something checked by a user-project called Smoke Detector (if you're familiar with it). Your post wasn't caught, likely because it wasn't posted for long enough to get scanned, but if it had, it would have been caught probably within five minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to prevent such questions without also blocking questions about handling such character programmatically.

Comment: @TinyGiant Seems like they could do a % check to compare the amount of non-Latin to Latin text outside of code blocks... If it's over n%, post a warning saying "it looks like you might be asking a question in a language other than English, if not, click through, if so, please edit your question to ask in English." May not be perfect but might help... though, I'm not sure how big of an issue it is in general.

Answer (score 10):

**Tl;dr**: I would like to see a "use this tag/these tags instead" feature integrated in the wizard.

---

We just had a bit of [discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6626/6102) over at the electronics site regarding the problem of company name tags, which is also a known problem at SO and possibly other sites too. In each case, what the poster is actually asking for is how to use a specific product from the company.

Getting rid of the company tags at this point, on a mature SE site, is a big undertaking with lots of work for little gain. Usually it means extra work for moderators. See for example the [burninate the Apple tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag) project at SO.

Now, rather than to burninate all these company tags on all sites, what about steering questions towards using better, correct tags instead?

That is, if we could make it possible to create tag dependencies between for example company tags and product tags, someone who posts a new question can be directed to pick some more meaningful tags instead.

For example: in the wizard, the new user types [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) in the tag selection window. They would then get some manner of dialog listing tags for various Microsoft products that the question is actually about. Visual Studio, SQL Server etc etc.

This could be used for all manner of undesired tags that should be replaced with more specific ones. This would give better questions (you aren't actually asking about the Microsoft company, you are asking about Visual Studio 2017) and also less boring busy-work burninate requests.

It could perhaps also solve the problem with recurring bad tags that have already been burninated, without the need of doing some blacklist procedure.

Answer (score 9):

Update: if you like this one, please consider Dukeling's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369699/3458) as well. I think he has a better set of options.

I think we need to be a bit more detailed under "Question about my code". There can be a catch-all, sure, but separate instructions for "Compilation Error", "Runtime Error", "Results not as Expected" would be useful, leading to slightly different multi-section pages prompting for concrete information.

E.g., compilation error could ask for actual line where error happens, Runtime error could ask for stack trace and mention debugger.

Comment: The compilation error vs. runtime error doesn't make sense for dynamic languages like Python, so "compilation error" should probably be omitted in certain cases.

Comment: @MathiasRav Python actually _does_ have a "compile time", it's just that it's a subset of runtime rather than a separate thing, and novice users aren't going to know the distinction. And similar things will be true for some, but not all, other "scripting" languages. Not to mention that plenty of people are running "compiled" languages like Swift or Go or Haskell in "playgrounds" that just have a "run" button, or even an interactive REPL. So, I think that the distinction maybe can't be in a radio button, but has to be covered in the general what-to-include text?

Answer (score 9):

Overall, this looks very promising, good stuff! Here's some feedback:

- Regarding "I need help with a software or hardware issue", it should probably be re-phrased as others have pointed out. Questions about writing software or using programmer tools are on-topic, including peripheral tools like version control. Writing shell scripts, batch files etc is also on-topic.

  Regarding "hardware issue", I'm unsure of how many posts that are re-directed to Super User, but I personally re-direct a whole lot of people to https://electronics.stackexchange.com. It would be great if we could suggest that site for borderline software/hardware questions. Such questions are on-topic on EE even if the problem turns out to be software-related, while they are off-topic on SO if the problem is hardware-related.
- The wizard seems to accept invalid tags. I told it to use [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) [world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/world), where the latter two are definitely invalid.
- I think formatting must be integrated in the wizard. It is very awkward to post code in it, I think the result with the current wizard will be a whole lot of unformatted code questions. At very least add 4 spaces before every row the user pasted as code before dropping it in the actual "Ask a question" form.

Answer (score 9):

First off, yay! Thank you! This looks like a great idea and I am looking forward to it. However, the example questions need to be very carefully chosen. I have seen two so far, and both are problematic:

> Say "I'm setting up a new server and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?

This is only marginally better than the counter example:

> Don't say "I want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application".

The only extra detail added in the "say" example is that the OP wants to set encoding/charsets. OK, but what server is this? Web server? Mail server? If web, is it Apache? Something else? Does it run on Windows? On Linux? On BSD? The choice of example question is essential, so let's make it as detailed as we can. For instance:

> Say "I'm setting up a new Linux apache web server (LAMP) and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?

The other example I saw was:

> Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP”

I realize I may be fighting a losing battle here, but can we please not suggest the ungrammatical "How to fix problem?" form? "How to foo" is a statement, not a question. Can we please change that example to:

> Say "How can I fix the 'Headers already sent' error in PHP?"

Or, if you don't want a full question, something like:

> Say "I am getting a 'Headers already sent' error in PHP"

Basically, we need to make very sure that the example questions are *perfect*.

Comment: Ideally we would make them links to actual well-received questions.

Comment: Also, some of the examples that are given in the yellow sidebar aren't the greatest. For instance, I was directed to [When catch doesn't actually catch anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378884/531762), which is a terrible title that new users shouldn't be emulating.

Comment: The example "good" questions should at least not be guilty  of the many common quality issues we see, which you rightly point out:  lack of specificity over environmental variables.

Answer (score 9):

Currently, the "We found similar questions that match your title" page does not make it clear that the proposed questions will open in a new tab when clicked. A new user on this page may be scared to click one in case their progress in the wizard is lost due to leaving the current page.

[image: Proposed questions page]

My suggestion for this would be to use the "external link" icon (see below) somewhere, maybe next to each link, or having "links will open in a new tab" somewhere.

[image: External link icon]

([Icon courtesy of IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/2561428/external_link_icon))

Comment: I've seen similar icons signaling that the linked resource was off-site...

Comment: @yivi Yes that's another possibility for confusion. Just an idea though.

Comment: Hopefully people asking a question on Stack Overflow would know that you can open a question in a new tab/window by middle-mouse clicking or right-clicking and selecting the option from the contextual menu...

Comment: @TylerH One thing I have learnt from the Internet, is that you can't assume anyone's knowledge.

Comment: @TylerH This will probably end up on the non-technical SE sites eventually and might be more helpful there

Comment: I believe that it also hinders the review process if someone has to consistently open in a new tab, rather than it being clear that this will happen by default. Especially on mobile for example, where opening in a new tab can be a cumbersome process.

Comment: And why not have a "tooltip" like preview of the question when hovering the mouse over it? I know, that might be hard, but worth a thought. And as written in my answer ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369793/1531124 ), currently further below: that whole suggestion of links is absolutely pointless **unless** the terrible internal search gets improved. The internal search is just lousy, and although people are complaining since years ... it is still  lousy.

Comment: @Tyler you forgot control+click.

Comment: @TinyGiant I left it out because I didn't want to then also include cmd+click for Mac users and a note that includes any other keyboard remapping people may had done themselves.

Comment: @TinyGiant Interesting, I've always just used middle click. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

Minor nitpick, during the wizard I was asked the question

"Do any of these answer your question?"

The only option was "next". When asked a question in real life, the usual answer is either "Yes" or "No". Yes is implied if you click away from a question and close the new question wizard, but I went to answer "no" and my only option was "next". It's pretty obvious what Next would do and it's intended design, but the language is clunky.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The hint box explaining how to post code could be customized to match the language tag - if present and if a single file makes sense for that technology. Talking about "file.php" to a C# beginner might be confusing.

[image]

Comment: That whole thing just seems wrong. What if the problem doesn't reside in line 12-23, what if lines 12-23 don't execute without supporting code. The advice given there is wrong, we don't want code copied from your project at all. We want generalized code the has been reduced to just what is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant The title in bold seems to ask for just that, you're nitpicking. Generalization is as well not always possible, and even if it is, asking everyone to do it is too much if we really want the site accessible for non-experts.

Comment: What if I'm asking about HTML/CSS/JS combo? Which filename should it use? Seems like a lot of work for what should be obviously examples. Or do you think beginners would be confused if they don't have a file.cs in their project?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's also what I meant, but obviously I didn't write it explicitly. I've improved the part - you are right that for some technologies it doesn't make sense to even talk about a single file.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a step too far regarding customizing help for users. If one can't think semi-intelligently about the files that are right there in the IDE, and make some logical deductions regarding the naming of files in an example, I'm not sure how changing the extension on an example file name is going to help bridge that kind of gap. That's the kind of basic computer skill that should already be in place for a professional or enthusiast programmer... But maybe that's the point, we're now a global helpdesk for everyone who picks up a keyboard.

Comment: I have to side with Tiny Giant here. That's not to say your suggestion is bad. It's actually great and I upvoted it. But what if one of the user's figurative lines 12-23 have a function like calculateFoo() and they include it in their code. Then we have to ask what that does, only to find out that it makes no difference and isn't related to their problem and it could be replaced with `true`. Maybe the sentence can be replaced with "Include lines from <file.cs|file.php|...> necessary to reproduce your problem".

Answer (score 7):

It's good that the wizard has formatting instructions, especially for users unfamiliar with Markdown. Unfortunately, the instructions are kind of hard to find...

[image]

...you have to find and click a nearly invisible light gray question mark icon.

[image]

Is there a better way?

Maybe replace the question mark with a link that says "Formatting help" or "How to format an answer", which would lead to the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page or a simplified version.

Comment: Would it be possible to just have the default view be showing the instructions?

Comment: @Mistella Sure, as long as there’s room on the page for it. I think there’s probably enough space for a summary and a link to more detailed info.

Comment: Does SO offer a short gif/gifs showing how to select and apply formatting options? So many times I feel sorry for OPs I see editing again and again trying to work out how to get code between code tags with correct indenting, to use Code tags versus snippet...... etc...... And that is just those that even succeed in getting that far.

Answer (score 7):

When I try to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to enter a word between code tags I get search Google as shown below. This is the same as doing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> whilst in the comments section under questions/answers.

[image: search google]

Is this intended? I find it confusing as I am used to this being the shortcut for adding code tags.

If this has been covered elsewhere, please let me know and I will delete this as soon as I receive the notification.

**FWIW:**

I found markdown formatting more difficult than usual using toolbar and had to resort to my own knowledge of how to directly apply formatting. I couldn't even bold with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> . I have seen formatting help mentioned already. This should be as easy as possible for new users. I mention in my comment on another answer as to whether there are any gifs/clips showing users how to apply markdown formatting on SO. A nice clear visual they can follow on screen. Again, perhaps this is already in the help centre. But clips really aid understanding I think.

Struggling with basic tasks like putting my code between tags has actually harmed the quality of my question in this test case. But, perhaps this is due to my lack of familiarity with this tool. I expected to be able to use the same techniques as I already do when asking questions without the Wizard.

Answer (score 7):

I just took my first look at the wizard. (As I’ve aged, I’ve become denser. Keep that thought in mind.)

I look at the options and I really wonder which does or doesn’t, could or couldn’t, apply to the specific question I actually  have. And maybe I should say “BEST apply” since they seem to overlap. Having said that, I might just pick “Other”. (Not really; devil’s advocate, but frustrated user’s safety valve?) I’m saying the intent of each alternative isn’t overly clear.

1. question about my code
2. software recommendation
3. software or hardware issue
4. homework problem

Are some newbies going to  have trouble separating the intent of the first 3? Software has underlying code. A question about code (#1) could involve getting a recommendation about how best to write that software (#2). And if I have a question about my code, well, then I DO need help with a software issue (#3).

I know each alternative would ideally be considerably less than one long line in length. Hovering the mouse pointer over a hotlink to further explain would suggest that we can’t figure out how to say it. And hovering gets old fast.

As I try to go on with my critique, I realize I can’t until I know the intent of each alternative.

But I’m going on anyway, having made certain vague assumptions.

Should you rephrase #1 to say, “I have a question about code I am working on”? I don’t know. I’m just asking.

Couldn’t you rephrase #2 to say “I need a recommendation about which software to use”, if that is what you’re saying? 
Or is the intent to encourage/enable questions about best practices in writing code? Or something else?

Why does #3 say “software OR HARDWARE”? Why not two separate alternatives? Ok, so take out “or hardware”; then it just makes the first 3 all the harder to separate.

How much help do we give help on homework questions? Ideally, we might apply the Socratic method in a chat. No thanks. But often Answers are nothing more than code that will do what the homework says to write. And that’s not help in the spirit in which it’s intended. How about #4 saying “I have a QUESTION about a homework problem”?

I’m not trying to be difficult or nitpicking. You’ll never get it to where nobody can misinterpret the intent, but page 1 of the wizard seems to be in need of wordsmithing.

Comment: I don't buy that someone could genuinely mix up "software recommendation" with a problem with code not working, but I agree they could be phrased better.

Comment: @TylerH--in all seriousness... Is either of my interpretations ("which software to use" or "best practices") correct? I have to admit that I haven't given help to many questions--maybe 1 or 2 per month--and then only if they involve Java or Android, so maybe I should either start following more Q&A threads than I do or let the experts handle this new, good idea. I *think* it's good.... But I now feel too ignorant and restrictively active to comment further.

Comment: Yeah, I think so; both of those quoted lines are common types of software recommendation questions.

Answer (score 7):

Dropping a small idea here as it seems appropriate:

Can we in a future release have a template for the question part of the wizard customized by tag and defined by the community in the tag's wiki (and fallback to the generic one if there's none) ? (using the first tag given to avoid conflicts in templates)

Something like the [multiple issue templates](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issue-and-pull-request-templates/) on github sounds appealing as the requirements for a Java question are probably not the same as those for a R question or a Go one for example.

Comment: By tag? What about multiple, conflicting tags? It seems like a very regular occurrence.

Comment: I'd go with the first tag, good point I forgot to mention it. (or maybe just fallback to default template then)

Answer (score 6):

I assume that this will be A/B tested in the near future. Some remarks about the kind of statistics that would be interesting to be able to view:

1. Proportion of users who click through the suggested duplicates list, compared to the proportion that view any of the suggested duplicates in provided when you type in the title in the current question format. This can indicate to us if having the possible duplicates on a completely separate page instead of something you can just scroll passed helps people find their answers sooner.
2. Proportion of users that click on the Programming Recommendation or Software/Hardware issues and then still manage to ask a question on Stack Overflow that is closed for one of those reasons, compared to those who don't ask a question here after viewing those pages. This could indicate to us if there are people who are not ignorant, but are explicitly choosing to ask off topic questions here even after being prompted not to, which, if it's common enough, could possibly warrant an added penalty system to people who do this.
3. Proportion of users who don't make it to the end of the wizard, compared to users who start a question on the normal Ask a Question page and don't end up posting one for whatever reason. We can hope that as people follow the guided question format that it can help them to discover their own answers or figure out where else to look or understand that their question is not a good fit. I would say if users who use the Wizard are less likely to ask a question, that's probably a good sign.
4. Proportion of questions asked through the Wizard that get closed compared to questions being asked through the normal Ask A Question box (in the same rep ranges). I hope that we see a decrease in the closure frequency of questions as a result of this Wizard.
5. Information on if use of the Wizard results in an influx of questions to Super User and Software Recommendations -- And if we're encouraging good questions to make it over there or if we're just moving our junk into someone else's backyard (This could be measured by questions by people who follow the link over to one of those sites and if they get upvoted, answered, and/or closed).

This type of data will help us know if the Wizard is helping Stack Overflow. If anyone else has other data points that they'd like to see reported as a result of the A/B testing, you can comment or add your own answer... Though this is the 50th answer to the question so I'm not sure if we want too many more :)

Comment: We're definitely planning on A/B testing this and we'll consider these!

Answer (score 6):

### I tried out the new wizard pretending to be a new user, and I ran into trouble trying to paste code.

This is the help for adding code:
[image]

#### The help gives the impression that the user has to hit the space bar four times for every line of code.

There should be a code button like the usual template, or the wizard should at least mention the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> shortcut for formatting code.

Since formatting is something that new users often mess up on, the wizard should put in every effort to turn out well-formatted posts. This has to begin with a comprehensive guide on how to format properly. This is one way that the wizard could really help. In fact, it is the obvious way to teach new users how to handle code in posts, *but the wizard is misleading instead of helpful*.

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request): **Please add the necessary material to help new users format their code**.

Answer (score 5):

I think the matched title search needs to work better.

Normally we put in the title first, then the question then the tags, so it's as good as it gets. Now we are putting in tags then title. The title search should reflect the tags. For instance I asked about Unity, and I had the Unity3d tag, but the first 5 titles had nothing to do with unity. Similar problems, but in other platforms making them completely unrelated. I got bored of looking at titles before I reached anything unity related.

**Now that we have the tags, we should show questions with the same tags first as suggestions for previously asked**

Answer (score 5):

> Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP”

I know that technically, this is "ok". The tag is not a tag but included as a part of the sentence. Meh. But please do not encourage newbies to repeat information. Their title should state what the problem is. I see too many titles that are basically just the tags with some auxiliary verbs sprinkled in. If it's tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) already, I don't need that repeated in the title.

And while we are at it: I think questions [should ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288090/shouldnt-a-question-ask-a-question), so even if you don't want to implement that in the wizard, it would be nice if we could at least lead by example and have our example headlines ask a question. Including the proper punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

How about using placeholders in the form?

[image: Question guide screen alternative]

This would allow the person to read all the examples immediately before writing (since some might not read/notice the changing examples in the sidebar).

I just used simple **unicode characters for the icons** in the placeholders:

```
Examples:&#10;&#x2714; “Include lines 12-23 of /file.php”&#10;&#x274C “Don’t paste entire /file.php”&#10;&#10;&#x2714; “Indent four spaces to format your code”&#10;&#x274C “Don’t paste line 23 only”
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the following wording is clear enough, especially to someone new to asking technical questions:

> Describe expected and actual results.

It would be better to be more explicit, along these lines:

> What result were you expecting to see?  What actually happened instead?

Or more in line with the existing wording:

> Describe the result you were expecting, and then describe the result that actually happened.

Answer (score 4):

It is great to get the opinion of veteran users on this much needed new tool...

**But is there a "next stage" of testing:**

## Getting new users (aka: zero rep) users to try it, without instruction

**... and see how they do?**

---

Unless there's major opposition to this idea, when I'm back on in a few hours, going through new VBA/Excel questions as regularly do, when I come across poorly written questions from newbies (Rep 0-5) I will ask if the user is willing to resubmit their question with this tool, with no input from me, then the user and I will look at the two questions, together decide which is better, and promptly delete the other one, and I will make notes on the process and report back here.

I'll only do this on 2 or 3 questions to start, but that's the true test of this wizard, right?  VBA is a slow enough category on a Friday night that any confusion over the duplicates will be minimal.

Comment: We’re actually doing both. We’ve been doing user testing with users outside of the meta community (even before we posted here) and we’re planning to continue doing so as we get closer to the experiment stage. Stay tuned!

Comment: @JonChan good to hear!  Will this testing include "brand new" (zero rep) users?  Seems to me that's where the real issues will come to light since they are the most likely to "break" the wizard, or to misunderstand the process.  The wizard is a great idea and I look forward to the full launch!

Comment: @JonChan I am curious if it will be obvious which questions were created by the wizard, and whether the user will be able to re-enter the wizard after the question is posted.

Comment: I haven't tried working my way through the entire template. I didn't know if there was a point of no return I might accidently skip over. If the system could recognise if this is the first time you have used the wizard and before/after submit give you  short scoring questionnaire e.g. ease of use 1-3 , were the question tips easy to understand, and a final suggested improvements free text box...... might this be a way to gather more feedback? The user could opt out of completing...... I guess could be detrimental if new users viewed it as an additional hurdle.

Comment: @QHarr actually on that thought, combined with my previous comment -- it would be nice if we could identify from SEDE which questions were produced by the wizard, because we could easily compare questions scores and results for questions with/without the wizard

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest making the:

> Please note this will post a real question on SO

A bit more obvious. I think having a 'prototype' function properly without it being clear with flashing lights and jumping around the screen, people will be posting low quality questions not realising they'll be real questions.

I already accidentally asked this question:

- [How can I remove an item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013771/how-can-i-remove-an-item-from-an-array)

I fully expect more people testing it by asking questions. I mean, it's a prototype that people want to try out... *don't make it post real questions!*

Comment: I agree; originally they didn't even have that notice and it was a big surprise that it actually posted your question... kind of dropped that ball a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a follow-up answer to [@CodeCaster's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369693/749227) about "where did the headers go?"

I think you can help by calling them out as distinct from the post content.  Also, making it more clear to the asker that the post preview is exactly how it will appear will guide them to that understanding as well.

[image]

Comment: In hindsight, I should have used `==` rather than `=` in the example. :)

Comment: I should also have made it an animated gif.  It's not entirely apparent unless you've used the wizard yet that the appearance of whichever section has focus is different.  Orange may be a bit over the top, but in my example it's denoting the active section of the 4.  Perhaps something less pronounced would be best. The main idea is to not have the prompts be just text-on-white similar to the user's content.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thank you for building this wizard, it seems magical and wonderful and sparkley. However, I've got a couple suggestions:

---

This screen appears after you click "I have a question about my code" or "I need help with a homework problem" (or "Other" then "Continue asking my question"):

[image: empty second screen]

It seems like this screen is full of blank space, which could be used for something better, and doesn't really do much to help the user ask their question. It would be great if we could either integrate this screen with the next one (somehow, I'm no UI expert) or use this space to explaining a bit about SO standards, maybe providing some links to the help center, or just talking about what SO is and what we expect from questions and what makes a good SO question.

There's all kinds of good stuff we could put here, and even though users can just click past, for those that do read it, it would be very useful.

---

On all of the compose screens (tags, title, description), there's a yellow box in the right sidebar:

[image: description screen]

To me, that feels outside of the normal flow that a user would be reading the dialogue in. We want the user to read that advice before they start typing, so I think it'd make more sense to stick that right above the text box, so that as you read down the page vertically, it fits in smoothly.

---

Besides these minor points and the other minor changes people have mentioned, this really seems wonderful. Thank you again!

One final question for y'all: (how) Will this get rolled out to the rest of the network if it goes well here on Stack Overflow? How are you planning on testing this? Is this already live for some users? How will you judge if this test was sucessful?

Comment: It's certainly live in some sense of the word.  If you throw in some random bad question data and hit 'Post', the Q. goes straignt on to the SO main front page.  I found out the hard way that the output does not go into a test database as I was expecting:)

Comment: Biiiig up-vote for moving the yellow box from the sidebar to the main content area. Stuff on the sidebar, while live-updating based on what is focused, is never as good or 'in your face' as stuff that breaks up the flow of content.

Answer (score 3):

When I was entering tags in the wizard I noticed some curious behavior. Perhaps this has always been going on, but today was the day I payed attention.

I want to enter the excel tag, so I start to type:

*Searching for* `E`

[image]
**Here are just the most used tags, and one relevant search result**

*Searching for* `Ex`

[image]
**Here `Javascript` and `Php` are still cluttering search results albeit being totally irrelevant** `Excel` should just occupy the second spot here, after the best match `Ex`.

*Searching for* `Exc`

[image]

**Only here `Excel` is in the first spot**

---

Also: Check out this beatifull allignment of the results box with the search bar:
[image]

Comment: It's because of the tag synonyms.

Comment: I don't imagine those synonyms were used much though? I guess those are weighted by popularity of javascript and php and not the synonyms, which I'd expect to be rare ('javascript-execution'?)

Comment: @TinyGiant, Yes I see those are underlined, but why favour a match in the middle of a string over a match at the start of a string?

Comment: @Kobi, some unwarranted passive aggresiveness from my side. Removed that.

Comment: @luuklag I'm sure the weighting algorithm considers more than just the position in the string where the two characters occur. It probably has a lot to do with the popularity of the tag because more popular tags are more likely to be used over less popular tags.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's my understanding of how the current search would work. But how would one want to end up with `PHP` when typeing `exc`?

Comment: As far as I can see in your example "exc" does not return php.

Comment: You are right, I meant to say `ex`

Comment: Well with "ex" it's just not specific enough. I mean, it's not going to be able to read your mind, and if it is tweaked just slightly enough that it works as you want here, it will fail elsewhere where it wouldn't have otherwise. Now if you typed in "ex" and the "ex" tag did not show up, then I would be concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Great start!  I love the helpfulness and positivity!

Using the "I have a question about my code" fork on the question [What is the Pythonic way to set up in a class a static dictionary that can be modified at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935092/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-set-up-in-a-class-a-static-dictionary-that-can-be-mo)

- Needs a Back button as well as a Next button that saves page state.  The tabs at the top are not obvious.
- "Tags" page hint "Don't include version numbers" is not always true.  In Python for example, the difference between 2.x and 3.x is often crucial.  Strike or improve this hint.
- "Description" page needs access to markdown language toolbar, not just the "Review" page.
- "Description" page needs hints for each section. Maybe best to put these in the Guided Mode box under each section heading.
- "Provide background and tell us what you've tried" should be split into "Provide background" and "Tell us what you've tried"
- "Provide background" should be fleshed out into types of background that are important.
- "Provide background" should be moved above "Summarize the problem"
- "Show your code" should be moved between "Summarize your problem" and "Tell us what you've already tried"

Comment: Upvoted for giving positive feedback first! Great idea!

Answer (score 3):

Looks promising, but there is more opportunity to prevent people from asking really off topic and otherwise completely inappropriate questions.

**1. Software reccomendation**

[image]

Off topic recommendation questions are not only about software and libraries, but also books, tutorials, hosting and just about anything else.

If someone wants to ask about best Java book, he will just select *Other* and will be blissfully unaware that this kind of question is not appropriate for SO.

Also, there is a difference between software and library, while libraries are software, they are also connected with coding... it is not absolutely clear that library recommendations are also off topic on SO (someone might think it is coding related question) and it is not absolutely clear that library recommendation questions are on topic (if properly asked) on Software Recommendations site.

[image]

Both of above issues with recommendations, could be solved if second bullet would be changed to *I need a software, library, tool,.... recommendation* and then next screen would give further pointers directing appropriate questions to Software Recommendations or saying that particular recommendation question is completely off topic for SO or any other SE site.

**2. Too broad**

Many bad questions are programming related, but just too broad. There should be a bullet for too broad "How to..." questions leading to page explaining what makes "How to..." questions inappropriate and how to ask good "How to..." question (if possible) that will not be closed as "Too broad".

Answer (score 3):

Please consider adding an additional prominent warnings for some tags which seem to attract a lot of off-topic fodder. For example, many SSH questions are off-topic because they concern themselves with SSH login, and not programming SSH.

The SSH tag has the warning:

> GENERAL SSH SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Secure Shell (SSH) is a cryptographic network protocol for secure data communication. Use this tag for programming questions related to Secure Shell....

A person who receives results without a prominent warning may be led to believe the question is on-topic when it is probably off-topic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just me, but I think the design of the tip/Eureka bulb can be improved:

[image]

Currently it looks a bit like a Venus symbol

[image]

which is cool in itself, but probably unrelated to programming.

To improve the current design, having either rays of light **or** the screw-in bottom part of the bulb **or** yellow color are [usual ways to make it more bulb-looking](https://www.google.com/search?q=light+bulb+icon&tbm=isch).

Comment: The feminine symbol is unrelated to programming, but so is a lightbulb. How would you *improve* the design?

Comment: @TylerH A light bulb icon is very commonly connected to "idea" "Useful tip", see [for example here](https://www.google.com/search?q=useful+tip+icon).  I edited the answer with improvement suggestions.

Comment: Or Kenny from Southpark.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of a wizard, but it really needs to stick to the basics. Perhaps for new users, all the screens can be included. For more experienced users though, the non-functional screens that comment on your selection will start to become annoying. Users could be required to use the wizard until they reach a certain reputation or for a set number of questions perhaps. For me personally, I would like the wizard to be mandatory for my first question, after which I should have the option to disable this.

I feel like all you need is the last screen, with the guided sections in the question body field, as below:
[image]

Maybe a checkbox can be added on this page where you can toggle the "Guided Mode" on/off. This way, more experienced users can have the freedom to do as they know is acceptable.

Comment: What you have described is a template, not a wizard, and it's already been tested/piloted for new users. This is a step above. And the whole thing is already targeted toward new users/askers so there should never be an issue of "for more experienced users [this] will start to become annoying".

Comment: FWIW (and at risk of sounding like a grumpy old man) a lot of this seems to be taken directly from the behavior I suggested in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard - including the conditions of who would see it: new users, new askers, and people who hadn't asked a question/many questions in a long time. So while I'm not affiliated with SO or the development of this feature, if I sound quite familiar with this, it's because I already recommended it last year :-)

Answer (score 2):

I like the wizard. It's coming along nicely. The only issue I see with it is that it does nothing to actually curtail bad habits. Instead it just tries to force the user to read everything. I feel like this will just improve user experience for people using the site correctly, and do nothing to people who don't understand what to do. The latter group of people seem likely to just do everything badly.

Can someone add logic to make sure the title follows the form of a good title and not a bad one for example? Can we test the input fields before letting someone continue?

Answer (score 2):

**Contextually ask for supporting documents.**

This might be supported by the suggestion to [allow for tag specific templates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370270/691711), but I'd like to specifically call it out.

Consider questions where a user is asking a [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) question.  Often times, I have to follow up with a comment asking what specific library is using or how they have their `scripts` configured.  It would be nice if the wizard specifically suggested to the user that they should include relevant information from their `package.json` file.

Similarly, I think [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) questions should suggest adding their `Dockerfile`, [ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant) questions should ask for `build.xml`, and [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) should ask for `makefile`s since I usually have to ask for those as well.  This basically extends to all configuration based tags.

I think this call out is more direct than asking for code.  The wizard asks users to include relevant code.  Someone running into an issue with [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx) will likely think "What code?  I'm configuring a server, the code doesn't matter" in which case we will likely have to ask the user to include their configuration file in a separate comment that wastes time.

Comment: Maybe instead of a custom template, it could display "How to ask a good question about [this tag]..."

Answer (score 2):

I would love to see integrated static analysis or code pattern matching.

- Does a Java question contain `(var == "str")`?
- Does a Bash question contain `var = "str"`?
- Does a Linux question contain `sudo echo`?

Common pitfalls like that can be easy to recognize by code, but hard to match by title because they're multiple steps removed:

- [Java - Small Rock Paper Scissors game. I can't find error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167766/java-small-rock-paper-scissors-game-i-cant-find-error)
- [Why doesn't this bash expr command work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785068/why-doesnt-this-bash-expr-command-work)
- [Can't write to file /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness (ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/484678/cant-write-to-file-sys-class-backlight-acpi-video0-brightness-ubuntu)

In the simplest case, this could be a per-tag list of regex and dupe targets that gets matched on whatever the user puts in the "code" part of the wizard.

Comment: I wonder if there's a [Stack App](https://stackapps.com) for that?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the wizard on mobile (Android) and desktop (Windows) but doesn't work. This is the first step. I'll only say the issues on mobile.

[image]

This looks OK but it's not like the Android design.

The second step doesn't work at all.

[image]

Here I got the default "ask a question" form on the regular site I've got this on the second step:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You click the "next" button and nothing happens? You click it and errors appear but you aren't scrolled to them automatically? It submits but shows you an error?

Comment: @TylerH I'm sure what he meant by it "doesn't work" is explained in the rest of his post. When on a mobile device, it shows the wizard using the desktop theme, but when he clicks next, the site switches to the mobile theme and the regular "ask" page instead of the wizard. I also reproduced the problem. I don't think this is an issue because they are probably not going to present the wizard for new users if they are in the mobile theme (hopefully). Besides, the mobile theme is (I believe) going to be retired once the responsive design is mobile-optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

> ### I need help with...
>
> - Fixing code that doesn't work *(Stack Overflow)*
> - Improving code that works *(Code Review)*
> - Hardware or software I'm using *(Super User)*
> - Business IT or networking systems I'm managing *(Server Fault)*
>
> ### I'm looking for recommendations for...
>
> - Which software to use *(Software Recommendations)*
> - Which hardware to use *(Hardware Recommendations)*
> - How to be a better programmer or software engineer *(Software Engineering)*

---

For comparison, here's the current proposal:

> ### What type of question do you have?
>
> #### We’ll help you find the best way to get your answer.
>
> - I have a question about my code *(Stack Overflow)*
> - I need a software recommendation *(Software Recommendations)*
> - I need help with a software or hardware issue *(Super User)*
> - I need help with a homework problem *(Stack Overflow)*
> - Other *(Stack Overflow)*

Comment: Did you mean to delete the 'other' option?  Stack Overflow isn't just debugging questions.

Comment: I'd be in favor of "Other" if it links to a page that provides clear guidance about which questions are on-topic.

Answer (score -4):

Many questions are not "about my code" -- but they're still on-topic:

#### "How to" or "How do I" questions

- [In Python, how do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)
- [Pythonic way to produce a list from nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029115/pythonic-way-to-produce-a-list-from-nested-dictionary)
- [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops?rq=1)

#### Theoretical questions

- [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)
- [Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures)
- [What is the Python equivalent of static variables inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)

So, how would those fit into the wizard's "What type of question do you have?"

***Edit 2018-07-02:***

Sorry downvoters, but I stand by what I said.

Questions including "Why," "What is," "How do I," and "Which way is better" are useful to thousands of people here. And Stack Overflow has so many of those questions that it's hard to make the case they're off-topic.

But if we don't want such questions anymore... then the wizard should say so, and redirect those questioners to a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: There are other choices in that initial list, like Other...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan "Other" and "Homework problem" have the exact same answer template as "About my code": *Summarize the problem. Provide background and tell us what you've already tried. Show your code. Describe expected and actual results.* But that template wouldn't work for many types of on-topic questions.

Comment: your **lost me with the very first example**, I just stopped reading because that question would be closed as at least **Too Broad** today **No MCVE**. It does not show any code. It is a *send me teh codez* vampire question in todays world. We do **not** want to encourage more questions like that. Especially because today they would be duplicates 99.999999999999999999999999999999~% of the time!

Comment: @feelingunwelcome Fair enough. Many questions in these categories are broad or duplicates. On the other hand, thousands of people believe “How do I” and theoretical questions on Stack Overflow are very helpful (and upvote accordingly). If we say they’re no longer within the scope of this site, that’s a major policy change.

Answer (score -5):

I think this wizard is great for helping new users with debugging questions, such as "Why isn't my code working?"-type questions. However, there are other types of questions out there. The wizard isn't very useful for those.

For instance, [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is a "what is" question.

Let's update the wizard to include all kinds of questions!

Comment: This was already covered much more thoroughly by [Tiny Giant in an earlier answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369706/7795130), and also mentioned by [abarnert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369700/7795130), and probably by another person or two in the already existing 77 answers. Is your answer really adding anything of value?

Comment: Perhaps a good way to make this answer more useful would be to provide a suggestion of new options to put into the wizard so that it does cover other types of questions, that way you're helping make the wizard better instead of just repeating something other people already reported.

Answer (score -7):

I went through the wizard and I lost my interest of even asking the question on Step 3 - "Tags" Tab. There's a lot to read. The point is, I want to ask a question and I expect the process to be simple and straightforward. I don't want to be stuck in the choices of categories, suggestions, etc.

"*Great! Our community is here to help you*" - Yes, I know that and that's why I am here. It is okay for people who are new to the community (that too for once or twice), otherwise its unnecessary.

I cannot get back to the previous options once I get to *Other* -> *Show Me Other Options*

**Step 3 - "Description" Tab**

I did like the idea of dividing the question in parts, but the problem is, questions don't come in a format to me, there will be times when my question cannot be explained in the specified format. Yes, the next tab does include the old editor, but if I don't know that, then either I will quit the process or will fix my question (after already taking time to fit it into the specified format).

**Step 3 - "Review" Tab**

By looking at this tab, I really feel that the previous three tabs were totally unnecessary. All the previous things are available to me at one place and that too in an editable condition. Why did I even go through the previous screens?

The process of asking a question should be very simple.

Comment: "The process of asking a question should be very simple, because the person who is "asking", is already in frustration or maybe is nearing a deadline, etc. Whatever the case, they expect it to be simple." While that's certainly unfortunate for them in many cases, that doesn't actually make it any more likely for them to be able to make a good contribution to the SO library, especially not if they suppose that asking questions on SO is as easy as falling off a log. Giving the wrong impression of what SO *is*, or *means* to be, is not what the wizard should do.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "that doesn't actually make it any more likely for them to be able to make a good contribution to the SO library", I dont understand, who are we helping? Our fellow programmers or StackOverflow? We do have downvotes for irrelevant questions, right?

Comment: We are helping our fellow programmers who read questions and their answers. Secondarily, we are helping the much smaller number of fellow programmers who *ask* those questions. SO is not mainly about askers. It's about search results, and perhaps 95% of site traffic comes from visitors who do not log in or post. Questions that are off-topic aren't primarily handled by downvotes, but by close votes.

Comment: Okay. Understood :)

Comment: "Nobody is going to see that you need an answer ASAP and then drop everything they're doing in order to help you. Your emergencies are your own... It might seem paradoxical, but if you're in a hurry, the best thing you can do is slow down..." ([Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/839601))

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ok, except from that, what else is not right in the statements I made? From line 1

Comment: So, it's working?

Comment: We tried simple, and have decided that there are too many people asking poor questions. So we are going to make it more complex in the hopes that the people asking the poor questions either go away or have their proverbial arm twisted into asking better questions. So as Kevin B said... it's working.

Comment: Finally someone does know how to appreciate opinions. Thank you @TylerH!

Comment: The only answer I agree with. Pages of helpful suggestions make people miserable, and miserable people don't ask better questions.

Answer (score -20):

A lot of questions that get downvoted seem to be victims of language barriers. I suspect that person asking the question sometimes don't know how to express themselves in Engrish.

Would it be possible to let people write questions in other languages (Spanish, Russian, Chinese, Thai, etc) and check a "I need help to translate my question"  checkbox? Then SO can put the question on hold in a translation queue where it can be picked up by someone willing to translate it into English?

Comment: If a person can't ask a question in english how are they supposed to understand/answer the comments and answers? Personally I never downvote a question because of crappy english.

Comment: From [this FAQ answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680): "They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate the post we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided (by comments, answers, or Help Center content).".

Comment: Redirecting people to the localized SO sites when appropriate seems like a better idea.

Comment: The localized sites have a smaller user base, getting things translated would mean the question (and answers) would reach more people.

Comment: Reading is usually easier than writing, so if somebody can write in sort-of english with a bit of help, then they will usually be able to read the answers as well.

Comment: @goleztrol good point. I can read in 4 more languages than I can write or express myself in. Thus, allowing people to express themselves in their native language and hope for a nice person to help them translate it into English would probably help a lot of users.

Heck, I even work with people where we send emails to each other in whatever language we're comfortable with writing in, knowing that the other person can read it but maybe won't be able to respond in the same language.

Comment: I disagree with the implied problem with **downvoting** non-English questions. Downvotes are perfectly acceptable in that case, just hover over the downvote button to see why. **Downvoting** is not a bad thing in and of itself, it is part of how the system processes anonymous feedback from the users to the users, stop denigrating downvoting, especially when the downvotes are deserved/earned.