# Shouldn't off-topic questions, once flagged, be removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

The sheer amount of off-topic questions on Stack Overflow is absolutely mind-boggling. The Stack Overflow QA model is supposed to promote quality questions and answers, but the off-topic QA's are deteriorating the content.

In my opinion, all off-topic questions, especially the ones that can't be moved to Server Fault, Security, etc. for whatever reason should be completely removed from the Stack Overflow site and points/achievements/reputation gained from answers subtracted from both the OP's and answerer's account.

Example: *[What's the difference between "grep -e" and "grep -E"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130299/whats-the-difference-between-grep-e-and-grep-e)* from 2013.

Why does this question still exist? It's already been closed as off-topic. Once it's deemed off-topic, shouldn't it automatically be deleted?

I also found dozens of others in less than 5 minutes that are blatantly off-topic, but they haven't even been flagged yet - and to find and flag all of them would be a full-time job!

Maybe a fair deterrent for posting off-topic questions could be a subtraction of user points or a change in user achievements, reputation, etc. once a question has been flagged off-topic.

Short of that, a huge popup that asks new users until N amount of questions have been asked, "Are you sure this is a programming question?" Or maybe a little AI that evaluates the content of the question and suggests the proper Stack Exchange sub-site.

Since Stack Overflow is so rife with an insurmountable amount of clutter, I think it's worthwhile to discuss strategies to deter and remove questions that don't belong (on a larger scale).

Comment: Questions are removed all the time. And reputation gained from deleted questions (or answers posted to deleted questions) is already removed.

Comment: Closed questions with low views and low score get automatically deleted anyway

Comment: @WhatsThePoint see my modified question with an example

Comment: @Sosukodo I did, even though something is off topic does not mean it is useful, closing the question just stops new answers going on to off topic posts, like I said in my previous comment, low scoring/viewed questions are deleted automatically

Comment: Re: automatically deleted closed question; [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Re: "*I also found dozens of others in less than 5 minutes that are blatantly off-topic but haven't even been flagged yet - and to find and flag all of them would be a full-time job!*", you're right, we're all just volunteers here. Re: "*a fair deterrent for posting off-topic questions*" user with many negative-score closed/deleted questions are already automatically banned from asking questions. Re: "Are you sure ... ?"; ["Ask a question" wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682)

Comment: Yes they should, but people answering and those answers being upvoted tend to get in the way of a swift cleanup.

Answer (score -7):

No. If they are good - having a positive score - then they are worthy content, despite their offtopic-ness.

They serve also as signposts to show, what type of questions are off-topic on the site. Their removal wouldn't make this example.

But the real reason is that the site won't remove good content, which is imho quite understable.

Closed questions with a negative score are automatically deleted by the Community user in 9, 30 or 365 days (I can dig out the link to the detailed rules from the MSE for ask).

*However, the correct way would be to migrate the posts to the site where they are on-topic, instead of deleting anything. Unfortunately, the SE somehow won't do it.*

Comment: `However, the correct way would be to migrate the posts to the site where they are on-topic, instead of deleting anything. Unfortunately, the SE somehow won't do it.` You know that you can flag for migration? And that they are migrated when the target site accepts them?

Comment: @BDL I know and I do it regularly, however it is not a very well-known thing. This results that many posts get an unfair treatment (closure, deletion), resulting a disappointed user about a single SE site. A migrated post means typically a satisfied user knowing already 2 SE sites. This is why do I think, that migrating posts is generally a good thing, particularly in comparison with the other options (closure, downs, deletion).

Comment: I agree with that. But your statement claims that migrations are not happening because SE doesn't want to. I'd say it isn't happening 50% because users don't flag for migration and 50% because the other sites don't want our waste.

Comment: @BDL The SE wants to minimize the migrations, if you don't believe it, then look for that on the MSE, I am now not in the mood to collect links for well-known facts.