# How to actually get the answers you are looking for?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Although I know and use SO for quite a long time already, I have never really asked questions there very frequently. One of the main reasons for that is that I am literally afraid of doing something wrong while asking a question because people are instantly going to call me out for it and/or downvote my question.

Despite trying my very best to first of all search for similar questions that are already answered, including as much information as possible in my questions and making sure it is clear what my problem is, it feels to me like I am constantly fighting against people that are trying their very best to find mistakes in my questions or write answers that do not actually answer my question (but are still upvoted by a lot of people). No matter how often I say and give reasons for why a certain answer is not helpful to me, people do not seem to understand it and keep pointing me to the not helpful answer over and over again. Take for example this recent question I asked where people constantly tell me to use the task scheduler:
[How to run some code at certain times every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541127/how-to-run-some-code-at-certain-times-every-day)

While it might be true that I could use the task scheduler, I cannot and do not want to do so because:

- I was told to implement this as a windows service
- The project is 99% finished already and I do not have the time to take the entire project apart again and implement it as an executable that I can call via the task scheduler
- I've had bad experiences with the task scheduler in the past where its entire service crashed or applications were not being executed as scheduled

Most of the time when I ask a question it just turns into a discussion about something that does not help me answer my question at all like justifying why I am not doing something else, explaining why I am not using library xy instead or pointing me towards a completely different stackexchange site to ask my question which usually has almost no active people on it hence I never get an answer to my question when asking it there at all.

What am I doing wrong? Why does it seem to me like people on SO are generally not very welcoming and how can I improve my questions so that I actually get helpful answers instead of downvotes (without anyone telling me why) or negative comments?

Comment: So your question contains **"Could I therefore please get some feedback on my idea? Is it good? Can it still be improved?"**, but not a single word about why you can't use something existing without re-inventing the wheel. Why? Important information belong into the question itself.

Comment: @Tom While it might be clear to you what information belongs into the question and what doesn't, it is far from clear to every new SO user. Therefore I have used the guidelines for asking questions provided by SO, thinking that following those results in a proper question. Apparently, it doesn't. Your comment is actually a perfect example for what I have described in my question here. Instead of politely pointing such mistakes out to new users, people are instantly bashing them for it as if they would have done the mistake on purpose to annoy other users.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being new to Stack Overflow, this is a simple rule about asking a question (in general). When you ask something and don't want to hear certain answers, then you obviously need to tell that the person you're asking.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, but to do that you would have to know everything that people might be telling you in their answers beforehand. And in my case I did point out multiple times that I did not want to hear that certain answer I kept getting, yet people were still pointing me towards that answer. We are just humans and therefore nobody here is perfect, thus I simply don't understand why everyone here seems to expect nothing but perfect questions on SO.

Comment: There's not much I can explain to you, because you already made up your mind that only perfect questions are allowed, that critique is bashing you, that downvotes are for bashing you and that important information and clarification don't belong into the question, but hidden in comments that are rarely read by everyone.

Comment: @Tom That is not something I just made up in my mind, it is something that the reactions from other users are continuously telling me subconsciously. Just like I am not putting important information "hidden in comments that are rarely read by everyone" to hide them, but I am doing so because literally the entire conversation regarding my question happened in those comments. When I am trying to directly respond to a comment then my logical sense tells me to do so with a comment, and not by editing the question.

Comment: I didn't see any unwelcoming comments on your post, you say task scheduler can't be used here but you don't include that anywhere in your question

Comment: *Could I therefore please get some feedback on my idea? Is it good? Can it still be improved?* Seems to very much fall into the subjective category as described in the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) help page. I'd also say that the fact the the comment section on that question has descend into a Q&A between you and a couple of users points at the question not being well defined. A good questions shouldn't need lots and back and forth to clarify

Comment: @Sayse Yes, because I simply forgot since I had no idea that people would recommend using it when I asked the question.

Comment: @Chris - Sure but then it might be worth editing that into your question when it becomes a common suggestion

Comment: @Chris people tend to recommend the simplest solutions, because that's how you build reliable systems. A lot of people succumb to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it's tedious to help a person wanting A, when he really needs B (without knowing it). The site works quite differently depending on your experience, with newcomers often hoping that they get an instant magic solution to whatever their question is. It's hard to help someone when they get angry at the help you give for free.

Comment: @Kayaman The problem with that is that the "simplest solution" is not always the same for everyone. When I have a 99% finished project where just one small feature is missing, it is certainly not the "simplest solution" to throw the entire project away and build something else based on a different technology, just because that would have been the simplest solution in case you were starting from scratch. That is usually the problem I run into when asking a question about something I'm working on and the answer I'm getting is that I should throw all of my work away and use technology xy instead.

Comment: @Chris and that's where your expectations and the answers failed to meet. But in your original question you didn't mention that you can't use it, and therefore got the "default handling". You're basically expecting that our answers should be better than your question, whereas our answers can only be as good as your question is. It's not a new problem, and I think the [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) attempted to deal with it, but I don't think it was a roaring success.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, but I added that information as soon as I saw what type of answers I was getting, yet people kept suggesting me the answer that I couldn't use all over again.

Comment: @Chris that can happen. There's no guarantee on getting the answers you want, or not getting the comments you don't want. I don't want people posting their homework questions (with no effort) directly here either, but that doesn't stop it from happening every day. We're still all humans asking and answering, but if you want to take out the human aspect and comments, just search the existing answers. You're unlikely to come up with a question that has never been asked before anyway.

Comment: @Chris yes, it'll still happen. But if your question had that information from the getgo (or gets it added), then you can at least explain why these answers that still point to the task scheduler can't help you. But you also have to remember that Stack is for the next visitor as much as it is for you. So making sure the next visitor knows that, the right solution is the scheduler, but that *in case* you can't use it, your question can help, is important

Comment: Side note: @Chris the way you worded your "because" section reads as "all developers are just incompetent as they can't implement such a simple thing as task scheduler when I'm almost done with one that is better than any other one around"... Assuming one SO question can provide insight how to implement something with production quality that at the same time is way better than existing production tools/libraries of the same kind is … a bit too optimistic.

Comment: The user does not want to use an out-of-process scheduler.  To me, that was obvious because the user did not use the OS task scheduler. It's fairly easy to maintain a delta queue of timeout times and 'creep up' on the nearest timeout with an ever-decreasing event or semaphore timed wait. That would seem to be what is asked for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beyond the specifics for your question, you ask:

> I have already created a possible solution but I am not sure if my solution is considered "good practice" or if there are any edge cases when my code will not work the way it should
>
> Could I therefore please get some feedback on my idea?  Is it good? Can it still be improved?

These questions are not a good fit for this kind of site. They are too broad and opinionated. "Best practice" questions are almost always primarily opinion based, and tend to be closed as such.

Questions should be specific and practical. E.g.:

- "How do I do X, using Y?".
- "Why while trying to do X using Y, I get Foo when I expect Bar?"

Asking for other users to review code and give their opinions is not a good way to use the site, and will get you poor results and a poor experience.

Let's try to see what else we can learn from this question for the future.

Say we remove all that. What are we left with?

---

The title of the linked question is *"How to run some code at certain times every day?"*. Using the task scheduler is a perfectly valid answer to that. If that's not a valid answer, for any reason, you should specify that in your question; so that potential answerers know of your specific constraints.

**Scope and constraints are vital to get useful answers.**

Your future questions should state up-front what specific constraints are you facing. Sometimes, even why you are facing these constraints (succinctly). If your constraints are very unusual, they may confuse your potential answerers if you do not explain them.

You do get into these constraints in the comments. **Do not do that**. Comments are mostly so other users can ask you for additional info and clarification about your post. Add that information **in the body of your question, do not get entangled in comments**.

The question needs to be complete. Comments are supplementary and should be considered ephemeral for most purposes.

---

Reading further, it doesn't look like you want to "run code at certain times", but that you specifically want to run an infinite loop, and conditionally execute the body of the loop, the condition being the time of the day.

**It's important that the question title better communicate the specific issue**.

---

Finally, it looks you have a "working" solution; but you simply want other user's opinions on it. This brings us back to the beginning:

This is simply not a good site for that kind of question. If you were facing specific problems with your solution, you could write a question about those.

But asking users to review code, or if a specific implementation is considered good practice or not (or good or bad), it's not a good use of the site.

Use this as a learning experience, take some time to read what the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) has to say on "asking questions", and your next efforts will be much better received.

Comment: How am I supposed to know this before asking my question? I personally do not think the same because I mainly wanted to know if my solution is **wrong** or if it will work **fine** and if there is any better way to do it. I also wanted to show my possible solution so other users have a better idea on what I am trying to accomplish. Overall I feel like asking questions on SO is like trying to walk through a minefield. If you manage to go through it without stepping on a mine, your question is good. If you don't, something is wrong with your question and you're going to get bashed and downvoted.

Comment: Mmmh. The site is complex, and it may do a poor job setting up expectations. Ok, now you know that this kind of question is not a good question for this site. Lesson learned. Now you can go the help-center and read about what's on-topic and what not. I sympathize with the confusion, but for your future questions you'll be better informed. While the site does have unusual rules, those rules are what made it successful and useful. I think that calling it a "minefield" it's a bit hyperbolic. The rules are not so difficult nor arcane, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I might have exaggerated a bit with that example and I agree that it shouldn't be so difficult to learn the rules. However, I am mainly talking about the experience for new users as it seems nearly impossible to me to have a great experience here when you are joining as a new user. You are pretty much "thrown into the cold water".

Comment: @Chris all of this is covered in the [help], specifically the [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section. I'd suggest you familiarise yourself with the topics in there.

Comment: @Chris I also highly recommend lurking around recently asked and well received questions on tags that may apply to your area of interest. What goes in to a question that does *not* descend into a back-and-forth in the comments? You’ll find these questions are usually well-researched and clearly explain the issue, *alternatives tried or considered that did work*, and pertinent background. The goal is that someone can read and fully understand what you need and can answer in a manner that may also help others in the future.